# Speed up the loop operation in R

Tags: performance, r, loops, rcpp, r-faq

I have a big performance problem in R. I wrote a function that iterates over a `data.frame` object. It simply adds a new column to a `data.frame` and accumulates something. (simple operation). The `data.frame` has roughly 850K rows. My PC is still working (about 10h now) and I have no idea about the runtime.

```
dayloop2 <- function(temp){
    for (i in 1:nrow(temp)){    
        temp[i,10] <- i
        if (i > 1) {             
            if ((temp[i,6] == temp[i-1,6]) & (temp[i,3] == temp[i-1,3])) { 
                temp[i,10] <- temp[i,9] + temp[i-1,10]                    
            } else {
                temp[i,10] <- temp[i,9]                                    
            }
        } else {
            temp[i,10] <- temp[i,9]
        }
    }
    names(temp)[names(temp) == "V10"] <- "Kumm."
    return(temp)
}
```

Any ideas how to speed up this operation?

Comment: Consider adding something like ```if(i%%1000) {print(i)}```while testing your function to get an approximate idea on the runtime

Answer (score 464):

Biggest problem and root of ineffectiveness is indexing data.frame, I mean all this lines where you use `temp[,]`.
Try to avoid this as much as possible. I took your function, change indexing and here **version_A**

```
dayloop2_A <- function(temp){
    res <- numeric(nrow(temp))
    for (i in 1:nrow(temp)){    
        res[i] <- i
        if (i > 1) {             
            if ((temp[i,6] == temp[i-1,6]) & (temp[i,3] == temp[i-1,3])) { 
                res[i] <- temp[i,9] + res[i-1]                   
            } else {
                res[i] <- temp[i,9]                                    
            }
        } else {
            res[i] <- temp[i,9]
        }
    }
    temp$`Kumm.` <- res
    return(temp)
}
```

As you can see I create vector `res` which gather results. At the end I add it to `data.frame` and I don't need to mess with names.
So how better is it?

I run each function for `data.frame` with `nrow` from 1,000 to 10,000 by 1,000 and measure time with `system.time`

```
X <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, n*9, TRUE), n, 9))
system.time(dayloop2(X))
```

Result is

[image: performance]

You can see that your version depends exponentially from `nrow(X)`. Modified version has linear relation, and simple `lm` model predict that for 850,000 rows computation takes 6 minutes and 10 seconds.

#### Power of vectorization

As Shane and Calimo states in theirs answers vectorization is a key to better performance.
From your code you could move outside of loop:

- conditioning
- initialization of the results (which are `temp[i,9]`)

This leads to this code

```
dayloop2_B <- function(temp){
    cond <- c(FALSE, (temp[-nrow(temp),6] == temp[-1,6]) & (temp[-nrow(temp),3] == temp[-1,3]))
    res <- temp[,9]
    for (i in 1:nrow(temp)) {
        if (cond[i]) res[i] <- temp[i,9] + res[i-1]
    }
    temp$`Kumm.` <- res
    return(temp)
}
```

Compare result for this functions, this time for `nrow` from 10,000 to 100,000 by 10,000.

[image: performance]

#### Tuning the tuned

Another tweak is to changing in a loop indexing `temp[i,9]` to `res[i]` (which are exact the same in i-th loop iteration).
It's again difference between indexing a vector and indexing a `data.frame`.
Second thing: when you look on the loop you can see that there is no need to loop over all `i`, but only for the ones that fit condition.
So here we go

```
dayloop2_D <- function(temp){
    cond <- c(FALSE, (temp[-nrow(temp),6] == temp[-1,6]) & (temp[-nrow(temp),3] == temp[-1,3]))
    res <- temp[,9]
    for (i in (1:nrow(temp))[cond]) {
        res[i] <- res[i] + res[i-1]
    }
    temp$`Kumm.` <- res
    return(temp)
}
```

Performance which you gain highly depends on a data structure. Precisely - on percent of `TRUE` values in the condition.
For my simulated data it takes computation time for 850,000 rows below the one second.

[image: performance]

I you want you can go further, I see at least two things which can be done:

- write a `C` code to do conditional cumsum
- if you know that in your data max sequence isn't large then you can change loop to vectorized while, something like

  ```
  while (any(cond)) {
      indx <- c(FALSE, cond[-1] & !cond[-n])
      res[indx] <- res[indx] + res[which(indx)-1]
      cond[indx] <- FALSE
  }
  ```

---

Code used for simulations and figures is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/tentacles-from-outer-space/so-2908822).

Comment: As I can't find a way of asking Marek privatly, how were those graphs generated?

Comment: @carbontwelve Are you asking about data or plots? Plots were made with lattice package. If I got time I put the code somewhere on the web and give you notice.

Comment: @carbontwelve Ooops, I was wrong :) This are standard plots (from base R).

Comment: @Gregor Unfortunately not. It is cumulative so you cannot vectorize it. Simple example: `res = c(1,2,3,4)` and `cond` is all `TRUE`, then final result should be: `1`, `3` (cause `1+2`), `6` (cause second is now `3`, and third is `3` also), `10` (`6+4`). Doing simple summation you got `1`, `3`, `5`, `7`.

Comment: Ah, I should have thought through it more carefully. Thanks for showing me the mistake.

Comment: Hello, which one is the code for dayloop2_C? And I what does temp[-1,6] means? negative indexed element?

Comment: @ShohamDebnath Code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/tentacles-from-outer-space/so-2908822). The C version is almost same as the B. `-1` is negative indexing and means "all except first", see [appropriate section of R introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-vectors).

Comment: Wow.. this answer might be one of the most helpful answers on this site. Reduced my run time from minutes to seconds

Answer (score 141):

**General strategies for speeding up R code**

First, figure out **where** the slow part really is.  There's no need to optimize code that isn't running slowly.  For small amounts of code, simply thinking through it can work.  If that fails, RProf and similar profiling tools can be helpful.

Once you figure out the bottleneck, think about **more efficient algorithms** for doing what you want.  Calculations should be only run once if possible, so:

- Store the results and access them rather than repeatedly recalculating
- Take non-loop-dependent calculations out of loops
- Avoid calculations which aren't necessary (e.g. [don't use regular expressions with fixed searches will do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458724/how-do-i-speed-up-text-searches-in-r/19458725#19458725))

Using more **efficient functions** can produce moderate or large speed gains.  For instance, `paste0` produces a small efficiency gain but `.colSums()` and its relatives produce somewhat more pronounced gains.  `mean` is [particularly slow](http://lookingatdata.blogspot.se/2011/04/speeding-up-r-computations.html).

Then you can avoid some particularly **common troubles**:

- `cbind` will slow you down really quickly.
- Initialize your data structures, then fill them in, [rather than expanding them each
  time](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2011/11/another-aspect-of-speeding-up-loops-in.html#more).
- Even with pre-allocation, you could switch to a pass-by-reference approach rather than a pass-by-value approach, but it may not be worth the hassle.
- Take a look at the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)  for more pitfalls to avoid.

Try for better **vectorization**, which can often but not always help.  In this regard, inherently vectorized commands like `ifelse`, `diff`, and the like will provide more improvement than the `apply` family of commands (which provide little to no speed boost over a well-written loop).

You can also try to **provide more information to R functions**.  For instance, use [`vapply` rather than `sapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply), and specify [`colClasses` when reading in text-based data](http://www.mollietaylor.com/2013/09/using-colclasses-to-load-data-more.html).  Speed gains will be variable depending on how much guessing you eliminate.

Next, consider **optimized packages**: The [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) package can produce massive speed gains where its use is possible, in data manipulation and in reading large amounts of data (`fread`).

Next, try for speed gains through **more efficient means of calling R**:

- Compile your R script. Or use the `Ra` and `jit` packages in concert for just-in-time compilation (Dirk has an example in [this presentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/useR2009hpcTutorial.pdf)).
- Make sure you're using an optimized BLAS.  These provide across-the-board speed gains.  Honestly, it's a shame that R doesn't automatically use the most efficient library on install.  Hopefully Revolution R will contribute the work that they've done here back to the overall community.
- Radford Neal has done a bunch of optimizations, some of which were adopted into R Core, and many others which were forked off into [pqR](http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/announcing-pqr-a-faster-version-of-r/).

And lastly, if all of the above still doesn't get you quite as fast as you need, you may need to move to a **faster language for the slow code snippet**.  The combination of `Rcpp` and `inline` here makes replacing only the slowest part of the algorithm with C++ code particularly easy.  Here, for instance, is [my first attempt at doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11275230/636656), and it blows away even highly optimized R solutions.

If you're still left with troubles after all this, you just need more computing power.  Look into **parallelization** (http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) or even GPU-based solutions (`gpu-tools`).

**Links to other guidance**

- http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/4/25/faster-talk.html

Answer (score 39):

If you are using `for` loops, you are most likely coding R as if it was C or Java or something else.  R code that is properly vectorised is extremely fast.

Take for example these two simple bits of code to generate  a list of 10,000 integers in sequence:

The first code example is how one would code a loop using a traditional coding paradigm.  It takes 28 seconds to complete

```
system.time({
    a <- NULL
    for(i in 1:1e5)a[i] <- i
})
   user  system elapsed 
  28.36    0.07   28.61
```

You can get an almost 100-times improvement by the simple action of pre-allocating memory:

```
system.time({
    a <- rep(1, 1e5)
    for(i in 1:1e5)a[i] <- i
})

   user  system elapsed 
   0.30    0.00    0.29
```

But using the base R vector operation using the colon operator `:` this operation is virtually instantaneous:

```
system.time(a <- 1:1e5)

   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

Comment: +1 though I would regard your second example as unconvincing as `a[i]` does not change. But `system.time({a <- NULL; for(i in 1:1e5){a[i] <- 2*i} }); system.time({a <- 1:1e5; for(i in 1:1e5){a[i] <- 2*i} }); system.time({a <- NULL; a <- 2*(1:1e5)})` has a similar result.

Comment: @Henry, fair comment, but as you point out, the results are the same.  I have modified the example to initialise a to `rep(1, 1e5)` - the timings are identical.

Comment: It's true that vectorization is the way to go whenever possible, but some loops simply can't be rearranged that way

Answer (score 17):

This could be made much faster by skipping the loops by using indexes or nested `ifelse()` statements.

```
idx <- 1:nrow(temp)
temp[,10] <- idx
idx1 <- c(FALSE, (temp[-nrow(temp),6] == temp[-1,6]) & (temp[-nrow(temp),3] == temp[-1,3]))
temp[idx1,10] <- temp[idx1,9] + temp[which(idx1)-1,10] 
temp[!idx1,10] <- temp[!idx1,9]    
temp[1,10] <- temp[1,9]
names(temp)[names(temp) == "V10"] <- "Kumm."
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I try to understand your statements. 

The line 4: "temp[idx1,10] <- temp[idx1,9] + temp[which(idx1)-1,10]" caused an error because the length of longer object is not a multiple of the length of the shorter object. 

"temp[idx1,9] = num [1:11496]" and
"temp[which(idx1)-1,10] = int [1:11494]"

so 2 rows are missing.

Comment: If you provide a data sample (use dput() with a few rows) then I'll fix it for you. Because of the which()-1 bit, the indexes are unequal. But you should see how it works from here: there's no need for any looping or applying; just use vectorized functions.

Comment: Wow! I've just changed an nested if..else function block and mapply, to a nested ifelse function and got a 200x speedup!

Comment: Your general advice is aright, but in code you missed fact, that `i`-th value depends on `i-1`-th so they can't be set in way you do it (using `which()-1`).

Answer (score 8):

As Ari mentioned at the end of his answer, the `Rcpp` and `inline` packages make it incredibly easy to make things fast. As an example, try this `inline` code (warning: not tested):

```
body <- 'Rcpp::NumericMatrix nm(temp);
         int nrtemp = Rccp::as<int>(nrt);
         for (int i = 0; i < nrtemp; ++i) {
             temp(i, 9) = i
             if (i > 1) {
                 if ((temp(i, 5) == temp(i - 1, 5) && temp(i, 2) == temp(i - 1, 2) {
                     temp(i, 9) = temp(i, 8) + temp(i - 1, 9)
                 } else {
                     temp(i, 9) = temp(i, 8)
                 }
             } else {
                 temp(i, 9) = temp(i, 8)
             }
         return Rcpp::wrap(nm);
        '

settings <- getPlugin("Rcpp")
# settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS <- paste("-I", getwd(), sep="") if you want to inc files in wd
dayloop <- cxxfunction(signature(nrt="numeric", temp="numeric"), body-body,
    plugin="Rcpp", settings=settings, cppargs="-I/usr/include")

dayloop2 <- function(temp) {
    # extract a numeric matrix from temp, put it in tmp
    nc <- ncol(temp)
    nm <- dayloop(nc, temp)
    names(temp)[names(temp) == "V10"] <- "Kumm."
    return(temp)
}
```

There's a similar procedure for `#include`ing things, where you just pass a parameter

```
inc <- '#include <header.h>
```

to cxxfunction, as `include=inc`. What's really cool about this is that it does all of the linking and compilation for you, so prototyping is really fast.

Disclaimer: I'm not totally sure that the class of tmp should be numeric and not numeric matrix or something else. But I'm mostly sure.

Edit: if you still need more speed after this, [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/) is a parallelization facility good for `C++`. I haven't tried using it from `inline`, but it should work. The idea would be to, in the case of `n` cores, have loop iteration `k` be carried out by `k % n`. A suitable introduction is found in Matloff's *The Art of R Programming*, available [here](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/132/NSPpart.pdf), in chapter 16, **Resorting to C**.

Answer (score 8):

I dislike rewriting code... Also of course ifelse and lapply are better options but sometimes it is difficult to make that fit.

Frequently I use data.frames as one would use lists such as `df$var[i]`

Here is a made up example:

```
nrow=function(x){ ##required as I use nrow at times.
  if(class(x)=='list') {
    length(x[[names(x)[1]]])
  }else{
    base::nrow(x)
  }
}

system.time({
  d=data.frame(seq=1:10000,r=rnorm(10000))
  d$foo=d$r
  d$seq=1:5
  mark=NA
  for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
    if(d$seq[i]==1) mark=d$r[i]
    d$foo[i]=mark
  }
})

system.time({
  d=data.frame(seq=1:10000,r=rnorm(10000))
  d$foo=d$r
  d$seq=1:5
  d=as.list(d) #become a list
  mark=NA
  for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
    if(d$seq[i]==1) mark=d$r[i]
    d$foo[i]=mark
  }
  d=as.data.frame(d) #revert back to data.frame
})
```

data.frame version:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.53    0.00    0.53
```

list version:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.03
```

17x times faster to use a list of vectors than a data.frame.

Any comments on why internally data.frames are so slow in this regard? One would think they operate like lists...

For even faster code do this `class(d)='list'` instead of `d=as.list(d)` and `class(d)='data.frame'`

```
system.time({
  d=data.frame(seq=1:10000,r=rnorm(10000))
  d$foo=d$r
  d$seq=1:5
  class(d)='list'
  mark=NA
  for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
    if(d$seq[i]==1) mark=d$r[i]
    d$foo[i]=mark
  }
  class(d)='data.frame'
})
head(d)
```

Comment: It is probably thanks to the overhead of `[<-.data.frame`, which is somehow called when you do `d$foo[i] = mark` and may end up making a new copy of the vector of possibly the whole data.frame on each `<-` modification. It would make an interesting question on SO.

Comment: @Frank It (i) has to ensure that the modified object is still a valid data.frame and (ii) afaik makes at least one copy, possibly more than one. Dataframe subassignment is known to be slow and if you look at the long source code it's not really surprising.

Comment: @Frank, @Roland: Does `df$var[i]` notation go through the same `[<-.data.frame` function? I noticed it is quite long indeed. If not, what function does it use?

Comment: @Chris I believe `d$foo[i]=mark` gets roughly translated into ``d <- `$<-`(d, 'foo', `[<-`(d$foo, i, mark))``, but with some use of temporary variables.

Answer (score 6):

The answers here are great. One minor aspect not covered is that the question states "*My PC is still working (about 10h now) and I have no idea about the runtime*". I always put in the following code into loops when developing to get a feel for how changes seem to affect the speed and also for monitoring how long it will take to complete.

```
dayloop2 <- function(temp){
  for (i in 1:nrow(temp)){
    cat(round(i/nrow(temp)*100,2),"%    \r") # prints the percentage complete in realtime.
    # do stuff
  }
  return(blah)
}
```

Works with lapply as well.

```
dayloop2 <- function(temp){
  temp <- lapply(1:nrow(temp), function(i) {
    cat(round(i/nrow(temp)*100,2),"%    \r")
    #do stuff
  })
  return(temp)
}
```

If the function within the loop is quite fast but the number of loops is large then consider just printing every so often as printing to the console itself has an overhead. e.g.

```
dayloop2 <- function(temp){
  for (i in 1:nrow(temp)){
    if(i %% 100 == 0) cat(round(i/nrow(temp)*100,2),"%    \r") # prints every 100 times through the loop
    # do stuff
  }
  return(temp)
}
```

Comment: A similar option, print the fraction i/n. I always have something like `cat(sprintf("\nNow running... %40s,  %s/%s \n", nm[i], i, n))` since I'm usually looping over named things (with names in `nm`).

Answer (score 2):

In R, you can often speed-up loop processing by using the `apply` family functions (in your case, it would probably be `replicate`). Have a look at the `plyr` package that provides progress bars.

Another option is to avoid loops altogether and replace them with vectorized arithmetics. I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, but you can probably apply your function to all rows at once:

```
temp[1:nrow(temp), 10] <- temp[1:nrow(temp), 9] + temp[0:(nrow(temp)-1), 10]
```

This will be much much faster, and then you can filter the rows with your condition:

```
cond.i <- (temp[i, 6] == temp[i-1, 6]) & (temp[i, 3] == temp[i-1, 3])
temp[cond.i, 10] <- temp[cond.i, 9]
```

Vectorized arithmetics requires more time and thinking about the problem, but then you can sometimes save several orders of magnitude in execution time.

Comment: you're spot on that vector functions will be faster than loops or apply() but it's not true that apply() is faster than loops. In many cases apply() is simply abstracting the loop away from the user but still looping. See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `accumulate()` function from `{purrr}` :

```
dayloop_accumulate <- function(temp) {
  temp %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
     mutate(cond = c(FALSE, (V6 == lag(V6) & V3 == lag(V3))[-1])) %>%
    mutate(V10 = V9 %>% 
             purrr::accumulate2(.y = cond[-1], .f = function(.i_1, .i, .y) {
               if(.y) {
                 .i_1 + .i
               } else {
                 .i
               }
             }) %>% unlist()) %>%
    select(-cond)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Processing with `data.table` is a viable option:

```
n <- 1000000
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, n*9, TRUE), n, 9))
colnames(df) <- paste("col", 1:9, sep = "")

library(data.table)

dayloop2.dt <- function(df) {
  dt <- data.table(df)
  dt[, Kumm. := {
    res <- .I;
    ifelse (res > 1,             
      ifelse ((col6 == shift(col6, fill = 0)) & (col3 == shift(col3, fill = 0)) , 
        res <- col9 + shift(res)                   
      , # else
        res <- col9                                 
      )
     , # else
      res <- col9
    )
  }
  ,]
  res <- data.frame(dt)
  return (res)
}

res <- dayloop2.dt(df)

m <- microbenchmark(dayloop2.dt(df), times = 100)
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#dayloop2.dt(df) 436.4467 441.02076 578.7126 503.9874 575.9534 966.1042    10
```

If you ignore the possible gains from conditions filtering, it is very fast. Obviously, if you can do the calculation on the subset of data, it helps.

Comment: Why are you repeating the suggestion to to use data.table? It has already been made multiple times in the earlier answers.