# Avoid the use of for loops

Tags: optimization, r, loops

I'm working with `R` and I have a code like this:

```
for (i in 1:10)
   for (j in 1:100)
        if (data[i] == paths[j,1])
            cluster[i,4] <- paths[j,2]
```

where:

- `data` is a vector with 100 rows and 1 column
- `paths` is a matrix with 100 rows and 5 columns
- `cluster` is a matrix with 100 rows and 5 columns

My question is: how could I avoid the use of "for" loops to iterate through the matrix?  I don't know whether `apply` functions (`lapply`, `tapply`...) are useful in this case.

This is a problem when `j=10000` for example because the execution time is very long.

Thank you

Comment: I think something has been lost in translation here?

Comment: Do you intend really to save in 'cluster' the last matching 'paths'?

Comment: Yes, what Musa and wkmor1 said... Did you really mean for i to got to 10... only testing the first 10 items in the 100 item vector data? ---

The general answer to your question is that you have to start thinking in vectors rather than individual items.  There are vastly faster ways to do something like what you're doing as soon as it makes sense.

Comment: thank you guys.
What i want to do is save in cluster column 4 values of path 2nd column when values from "data" are equal to values from "paths" and avoid the "for" sentence because when i have a lot of observations computational time increase highly

Comment: And what do you want to do when they are not equal?... they're just ignored?... or is the cluster column 4 already set to something that doesn't change unless this condition is met. (sounds like a simple ifelse() command-- no loops-- check help)

Comment: @albergali In last line of your code should be there `cluster[j,4] <- paths[j,2]`

Answer (score 1):

Inner loop could be vectorized

```
cluster[i,4] <- paths[max(which(data[i]==paths[,1])),2]
```

but check Musa's comment. I think you indented something else.

Second (outer) loop could be vectorize either, by replicating vectors but

1. if `i` is only 100 your speed-up don't be large
2. it will need more RAM

---

[edit]
As I understood your comment can you just use logical indexing?

```
indx <- data==paths[, 1]
cluster[indx, 4] <- paths[indx, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that both loops can be vectorized using the following:

```
cluster[na.omit(match(paths[1:100,1],data[1:10])),4] = paths[!is.na(match(paths[1:100,1],data[1:10])),2]
```

Comment: I wonder how the performance of your vectorized solution compares to the looping alternative.

Comment: @Guido In this particular case it's hard to say cause results from original loop and gd047 solution differ, but in general difference between loop and vectorized code could be huge. Check my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r, where from hours you can go to less than second.

Comment: @Marek Using randomized test matrices I got equal cluster matrices using both methods. I checked the results using `all.equal(loop_sol,vect_sol)` Which are the the test matrices that you have used and gave you different results?

Comment: @gd047 Check this http://sites.google.com/site/fsh9rss8heh/ (too long for comment), I use R-2.10.1

Comment: @Marek Thanks. You are right. In my examples there were not more than one matches between data[i] and paths[j,1]. In the general case where there are more than one, the dominant is the one that is checked last. I am not sure which one dominates in the vectorized way. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @gd047 As states in `help("match")` return **positions of (first) matches**, so you could write you own version using rev `match_last <- function(x,y) length(y)-match(x,rev(y))+1`

Comment: @Marek Nice idea but there's still a difference.