# In R, how do you loop over the rows of a data frame really fast?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, iteration, rows

Suppose that you have a data frame with many rows and many columns.

The columns have names. You want to access rows by number, and columns by name.

For example, one (possibly slow) way to loop over the rows is

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  print(df[i, "column1"])
  # do more things with the data frame...
}
```

Another way is to create "lists" for separate columns (like `column1_list = df[["column1"]`), and access the lists in one loop. This approach might be fast, but also  inconvenient if you want to access many columns.

Is there a fast way of looping over the rows of a data frame? Is some other data structure better for looping fast?

Comment: How is this different than df[, "column1"]? Also see ?apply with margin = 1.

Comment: The example was not what I really wanted to do. I wanted to write some values in the data frame as data in a javascript file. +1 for the information about "margin" in "apply".

Comment: I needed to loop over rows to move around values in columns under particular situations. I was reminded that the better way to do this in R is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746567/how-to-swap-values-between-2-columns

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think I need to make this a full answer because I find comments harder to track and I already lost one comment on this... There is an example by [nullglob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129836/loops-inefficiency-in-r) that demonstrates the differences among for, and apply family functions much better than other examples.  When one makes the function such that it is very slow then that's where all the speed is consumed and you won't find differences among the variations on looping.  But when you make the function trivial then you can see how much the looping influences things.

I'd also like to add that some members of the apply family unexplored in other examples have interesting performance properties.  First I'll show replications of nullglob's relative results on my machine.

```
n <- 1e6
system.time(for(i in 1:n) sinI[i] <- sin(i))
  user  system elapsed 
 5.721   0.028   5.712 

lapply runs much faster for the same result
system.time(sinI <- lapply(1:n,sin))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.353   0.012   1.361
```

He also found sapply much slower.  Here are some others that weren't tested.

Plain old apply to a matrix version of the data...

```
mat <- matrix(1:n,ncol =1),1,sin)
system.time(sinI <- apply(mat,1,sin))
   user  system elapsed 
  8.478   0.116   8.531
```

So, the apply() command itself is substantially slower than the for loop.  (for loop is not slowed down appreciably if I use sin(mat[i,1]).

Another one that doesn't seem to be tested in other posts is tapply.

```
system.time(sinI <- tapply(1:n, 1:n, sin))
   user  system elapsed 
 12.908   0.266  13.589
```

Of course, one would never use tapply this way and it's utility is far beyond any such speed problem in most cases.

Comment: +1 for the reference to nullglob. His post has a reference to the article "How Can I Avoid This Loop or Make It Faster?", by Uwe Ligges and John Fox, in "R News", May 2008. Thank you for writing about the apply functions.

Answer (score 12):

The fastest way is to *not loop* (i.e. vectorized operations).  One of the only instances in which you need to loop is when there are dependencies (i.e. one iteration depends on another).    Otherwise, try to do as much vectorized computation outside the loop as possible.

If you *do* need to loop, then using a `for` loop is essentially as fast as anything else (`lapply` can be a little faster, but [other `apply` functions tend to be around the same speed as `for`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar/2276001#2276001)).

Comment: Maybe there is no way to avoid the loop for what I wanted to do---see my response to Greg's comment above.

Comment: "around the same speed"? Did you read all the answers? In my answer there, I show that using vapply is 3x faster (for that example) than the for loop...

Comment: In terms of algorithmic efficiency, they are very similar in speed:
[algorithmic efficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency)

Comment: vectorized version does be more efficient than for-loop version, thanks @Shane

Answer (score 2):

Exploiting the fact that data.frames are essentially lists of column vectors, one can use do.call to apply a function with the arity of the number of columns over each column of the data.frame (similar to a "zipping" over a list in other languages).

```
do.call(paste, data.frame(x=c(1,2), z=c("a","b"), z=c(5,6)))
```

Comment: But that is not looping.

Comment: Great answer, the OP clearly asked 'how do you loop over the rows'. This is by far the most efficient method to do so, and doesn't at all require `for`. I had a `for` loop and now took this approach, which improved speed around a factor 40!