# How to swap values between two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with three variables and 250K records. As an example consider

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,4), V2=c("a","a","b"), V3=c(2,3,1))
V1 V2 V3
1  a  2
2  a  3
4  b  1
```

and want to swap values between V1 and V3 based on the value of V2 as follows: 
if `V2 == 'b'` then `V1 <- V3` and `V3 <- V1`
resulting in

```
V1 V2 V3
1  a  2
2  a  3
1  b  4
```

I tried a do loop but it takes forever. If I use Perl, it takes seconds. I believe this task can be done efficiently in R as well. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious how this situation came up, if you don't mind my asking. I have some experience using software that is at least sort of designed to work with survey data, but as we follow the trend of integrating with IT databases, questions of data structure have started coming up and I've needed to start thinking consciously about how we store stuff in tables. That's why I'm curious how your situation came up :)

Comment: Very common problem where Latitude and Longitude co-ordinates are manually entered in the wrong respective columns, for example

Answer (score 23):

Try this

```
 df <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,4), V2=c("a","a","b"), V3=c(2,3,1))
 df[df$V2 == "b", c("V1", "V3")] <- df[df$V2 == "b", c("V3", "V1")]
```

which yields:

```
> df
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  a  2
2  2  a  3
3  1  b  4
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `transform` to do this.

```
df <- transform(df, V3 = ifelse(V2 == 'b', V1, V3), V1 = ifelse(V2 == 'b', V3, V1))
```

Comment: I am trying                                                           
x=read.table("1.txt")                                      
x <- transform(x, x[[1]] <- ifelse(x[[1]]>x[[2]], x[[2]], x[[1]]), x[[2]] <- ifelse(x[[1]]>x[[2]], x[[1]], x[[2]]))                   

but no success!

Answer (score 4):

*Editted* I got tripped up with column names, sorry. This works.

If you don't mind the rows ending up in different orders, this is kind of a 'cute' way to do this:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("V1 V2 V3
1  a  2
2  a  3
4  b  1"),sep = "",header = TRUE)

tmp <- dat[dat$V2 == 'b',3:1]
colnames(tmp) <- colnames(dat)
rbind(dat[dat$V2 != 'b',],tmp)
```

Basically, that's just grabbing the rows where `V2 == 'b'`, reverses the columns and slaps it back together with everything else. This can be extended if you have more columns that don't need switching; you'd just use an integer index with those values transposed, rather than just `3:1`.