# If value in one column is greater than the value of another then interchange the values in the columns in R

Tags: r

I want to write a code that checks two columns in a dataframe and compares them. one is supposed to be the Max Temp and the other is Min Temp. if values of Tmax column is less than the Tmin, then it should interchange the values. I need to do this for multiple files in a folder.

```
        Date    TMAX    TMIN
1 01/01/1960  4.7353 -4.3722
2 01/02/1960  8.3800 11.0600
3 01/03/1960  3.4400 -3.5300
4 01/04/1960 -1.4300 -8.2200
5 01/05/1960 -1.9600 -5.0100
6 01/06/1960  4.5800 -6.3400
7 01/07/1960 -8.8900 -2.7300
```

after running the code, it should produce something like

```
        Date    TMAX    TMIN
1 01/01/1960  4.7353 -4.3722
2 01/02/1960 11.0600  8.3800
3 01/03/1960  3.4400 -3.5300
4 01/04/1960 -1.4300 -8.2200
5 01/05/1960 -1.9600 -5.0100
6 01/06/1960  4.5800 -6.3400
7 01/07/1960 -2.7300 -8.8900
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to swap values between 2 columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746567/how-to-swap-values-between-2-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
df <- data.frame(TMAX=1:5,TMIN=c(2,1,6,3,4))
dfn <- df
dfn$TMAX <- pmax(df$TMIN,df$TMAX)
dfn$TMIN <- pmin(df$TMIN,df$TMAX)
##   TMAX TMIN
## 1    2    1
## 2    2    1
## 3    6    3
## 4    4    3
## 5    5    4
```

Comment: Thank You for your help, however this adds two more columns to my dataframe. I just need the same format as my original data

Comment: really? can you give a reproducible example that shows that?  (Maybe the capitalization is different in your real data set?)

Answer (score 3):

```
dplyr::mutate(df, TMAX = pmax(TMAX, TMIN), TMIN = pmin(TMAX, TMIN))
```

Or just

```
transform(df, TMAX = pmax(TMAX, TMIN), TMIN = pmin(TMAX, TMIN))
```

Comment: Replace `dplyr::mutate` with `transform` and you've got a base R solution

Comment: I tried your second option but it does not solve my problem. i am new to r and did not understand how to run the first option

Answer (score 1):

(Maybe not the most elegant way) Assuming your data is called `df`:

```
check<-df[,2]>df[,3]

dfn<-df
dfn[!check,3]<-df[!check,2]
dfn[!check,2]<-df[!check,3]
```

And a more elegant way is:

```
transform(df, V2=ifelse(V2<V3,V3,V2),V3= ifelse(V3>V2,V2,V3))
```