# Swapping values between two columns using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, swap

I have been breaking my head over translating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746567/how-to-swap-values-between-2-columns) to a `data.table` solution. (to keep it simple I'll use the same data set)
When `V2 == "b` I want to swap the columns between `V1 <-> V3`.

```
dt <- data.table(V1=c(1,2,4), V2=c("a","a","b"), V3=c(2,3,1))
#V1 V2 V3
#1:  1  a  2
#2:  2  a  3
#3:  4  b  1
```

The code below would be the working solution for `data.frame`, however because of the amount of frustration this has given me because I was using a `data.table` without realising I'm now determined to find a solution for data.table.

```
dt <- data.table(V1=c(1,2,4), V2=c("a","a","b"), V3=c(2,3,1))
df <- as.data.frame(dt)
df[df$V2 == "b", c("V1", "V3")] <- df[df$V2 == "b", c("V3", "V1")] 
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  a  2
#2  2  a  3
#3  1  b  4
```

I have tried writing a `lapply` function looping through my target swapping list, tried to narrow down the problem to only replace one value, attempted to call the column names in different ways but all without success.
This was the closest attempt I've managed to get:

```
> dt[dt$V2 == "b", c("V1", "V3")] <- dt[dt$V2 == "b", c(V3, V1)]
#Warning messages:
#1: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, dt$V2 == "b", c("V1", "V3"), value = c(1,  :
#  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'V1' (1 unused)
#2: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, dt$V2 == "b", c("V1", "V3"), value = c(1,  :
#  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'V3' (1 unused)
```

How can we get the data.table solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can try

```
dt[V2=="b", c("V3", "V1") := .(V1, V3)]
```

Comment: I guess using `.SD` is faster than passing `list(V1, V3)`?

Comment: @BenBarnes I didn't test whether it will be faster, looks like `list(V1, V3)` would be fine too.

Comment: @eddi, what you have against `.SDcols`? I think it is more robust solution in case you have a vector of predefined columns.

Comment: @DavidArenburg that's a strange question :) I have nothing against `.SDcols` when it's used appropriately. In this case all it did was add extra symbols to type and make the solution more opaque.

Answer (score 2):

For amusement only. @akruns' solution is clearly superior. I reasoned that I could create a temporary copy, make the conditional swap, and then delete the copy all using `[.data.table` operations in sequence:

```
 dt[, tv1 := V1][V2=="b", V1 := V3][V2=="b", V3 := tv1][ , tv1 := NULL]

> dt
   V1 V2 V3
1:  1  a  2
2:  2  a  3
3:  1  b  4
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I was swapping the "a" values instead of the "b" values. Seems hardly worth fixing since it's going to be so slow. I only posted it so people could throw tomatoes.

Comment: at least do a `bitwXor` solution if you're aiming for amusing; not amused as-is

Comment: I wish I knew what a `bitwXor` was. Guess I will need to do some searching.