# What are the advantages of the "apply" functions? When are they better to use than "for" loops, and when are they not?

Tags: parsing, r, for-loop, compilation, lapply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is R's apply family more than syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar)

Just what the title says. Stupid question, perhaps, but my understanding has been that when using an "apply" function, the iteration is performed in compiled code rather than in the R parser. This would seem to imply that lapply, for instance, is only faster than a "for" loop if there are a great many iterations and each operation is relatively simple. For instance, if a single call to a function wrapped up in lapply takes 10 seconds, and there are only, say, 12 iterations of it, I would imagine that there's virtually no difference at all between using "for" and "lapply".

Now that I think of it, if the function inside the "lapply" has to be parsed anyway, why should there be ANY performance benefit from using "lapply" instead of "for" unless you're doing something that there are compiled functions for (like summing or multiplying, etc)?

Thanks in advance!

Josh

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2275896/429846

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5533246/210673

Comment: There is also a great R Help Desk article on this from back in May, 2008: http://promberger.info/files/rnews-vectorvsloops2008.pdf

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129836/loops-inefficiency-in-r

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several reasons why one might prefer an `apply` family function over a `for` loop, or vice-versa.

Firstly, `for()` and `apply()`, `sapply()` will generally be just as quick as each other if executed correctly. `lapply()` does more of it's operating in compiled code within the R internals than the others, so can be faster than those functions. It appears the speed advantage is greatest when the act of "looping" over the data is a significant part of the compute time; in many general day-to-day uses you are unlikely to gain much from the inherently quicker `lapply()`. In the end, these all will be calling R functions so they need to be interpreted and then run.

`for()` loops can often be easier to implement, especially if you come from a programming background where loops are prevalent. Working in a loop may be more natural than forcing the iterative computation into one of the `apply` family functions. However, to use `for()` loops properly, you need to do some extra work to set-up storage and manage plugging the output of the loop back together again. The `apply` functions do this for you automagically. E.g.:

```
IN <- runif(10)
OUT <- logical(length = length(IN))
for(i in IN) {
    OUT[i] <- IN > 0.5
}
```

that is a **silly** example as `>` is a vectorised operator but I wanted something to make a point, namely that you have to manage the output. The main thing is that with `for()` loops, you **always** allocate sufficient storage to hold the outputs before you start the loop. If you don't know how much storage you will need, then allocate a reasonable chunk of storage, and then in the loop check if you have exhausted that storage, and bolt on another big chunk of storage.

The main reason, in my mind, for using one of the `apply` family of functions is for more elegant, readable code. Rather than managing the output storage and setting up the loop (as shown above) we can let R handle that and succinctly ask R to run a function on subsets of our data. Speed *usually* does not enter into the decision, for me at least. I use the function that suits the situation best and will result in simple, easy to understand code, because I'm far more likely to waste more time than I save by always choosing the fastest function if I can't remember what the code is doing a day or a week or more later!

The `apply` family lend themselves to scalar or vector operations. A `for()` loop will often lend itself to doing multiple iterated operations using the same index `i`. For example, I have written code that uses `for()` loops to do *k*-fold or bootstrap cross-validation on objects. I probably would never entertain doing that with one of the `apply` family as each CV iteration needs multiple operations, access to lots of objects in the current frame, and fills in several output objects that hold the output of the iterations.

As to the last point, about why `lapply()` can possibly be faster that `for()` or `apply()`, you need to realise that the "loop" can be performed in interpreted R code or in compiled code. Yes, both will still be calling R functions that need to be interpreted, but if you are doing the looping and calling directly from compiled C code (e.g. `lapply()`) then that is where the performance gain can come from over `apply()` say which boils down to a `for()` loop in actual R code. See the source for `apply()` to see that it is a wrapper around a `for()` loop, and then look at the code for `lapply()`, which is:

```
> lapply
function (X, FUN, ...) 
{
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
        X <- as.list(X)
    .Internal(lapply(X, FUN))
}
<environment: namespace:base>
```

and you should see why there can be a difference in speed between `lapply()` and `for()` and the other `apply` family functions. The `.Internal()` is one of R's ways of calling compiled C code used by R itself. Apart from a manipulation, and a sanity check on `FUN`, the entire computation is done in C, calling the R function `FUN`. Compare that with the source for `apply()`.

Comment: Nice!  You managed to add new information beyond that in the related questions too.  Thanks, I learned a few new things.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'd like to clarify one thing regarding the potential performance gain. The code that's being executed inside the call to lapply() is still going to take just as long per iteration, right? So would I be correct in stating that in a situation where each iteration itself is taking on the order of several seconds or more that the performance gain over apply() or for() would be negligible?

Answer (score 3):

From Burns' [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (pdf), p25:

> Use an explicit `for` loop when each
>   iteration is a non-trivial task. But a
>   simple loop can be more clearly and
>   compactly expressed using an `apply`
>   function. There is at least one
>   exception to this rule ... if the result will
>   be a list and some of the components
>   can be `NULL`, then a for loop is
>   trouble (big trouble) and `lapply` gives
>   the expected answer.

Comment: Disagree entirely.  If the iteration is a non-trivial task, you're better off moving that block of code into a proper function and then calling it with the *apply().