# How to get rid of this for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am told that there is no need to have a "for" loop in R at all.   So, I want to see how I can get rid of this Python-like "for" loop in my R code:

```
  diff.vec = c()   # vector of differences
  for (index in 1:nrow(yrdf)) {   # yrdf is a data frame 
    if (index == numrows) {
      diff = NA  # because there is no entry "below" it
    } else {
      val_index = yrdf$Adj.Close[index] 
      val_next = yrdf$Adj.Close[index+1]
      diff = val_index - val_next   #  diff between two adjacent values
      diff = diff/yrdf$Adj.Close[index+1] * 100.0
    }
    diff.vec<-c(diff.vec,diff) # append to vector of differences
  }
```

Comment: There is a `diff` function to get the difference of adjacent elemetns in `R`  Also, check the `lead` and `lag` functions in `dplyr`

Comment: Whoever told you that is wrong.  Some operations will require a loop.

Comment: There are times when `for loops` are the preferred method. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6466415/4408538) post for a detailed explanation of when to implement a `for loop`. Check out these posts to to get a better understanding of R’s looping constructs: [post1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2276001/4408538), and [post2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28983292/4408538).

Comment: Whoever told you that probably wants you to wrap your operations in an `apply` function... which is just a for loop in disguise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, there are three reasons to avoid a `for` loop. The first is that they can be difficult to read by others (if you share your code), and the `apply` family of functions can improve that (and be more explicit on returns). The second is a speed advantage made possible under some circumstances, particularly if you move to make the code run in parallel (e.g., most `apply` functions are embarrassingly parallel, while `for` loops take much more work to break apart).

However, it is the third reason that serves you here: vectorized solutions are often better than any of the above because it avoids repeated calls (e.g., your `c` at the end of the loop, the `if` check, etc.). Here, you can accomplish everything with a single vectorized call.

First, some sample data

```
set.seed(8675309)
yrdf <- data.frame(Adj.Close = rnorm(5))
```

Then, we multiply everything by `100`, take the `diff` of the adjacent entries in `Adj.Close` and use vectorized division to divide by the following entry. Note that I need to pad with `NA` if (and only if) you want the outcome to be the same length as the input. If you don't want/need that `NA` at the end of the vector, it can be even easier.

```
100 * c(diff(yrdf$Adj.Close),NA) / c(yrdf$Adj.Close[2:nrow(yrdf)], NA)
```

Returns

```
[1] 238.06442 216.94975 130.41349 -90.47879        NA
```

And, to be explicit, here is the `microbenchmark` comparison:

```
myForLoop <- function(){
  numrows = nrow(yrdf)
  diff.vec = c()   # vector of differences
  for (index in 1:nrow(yrdf)) {   # yrdf is a data frame 
    if (index == numrows) {
      diff = NA  # because there is no entry "below" it
    } else {
      val_index = yrdf$Adj.Close[index] 
      val_next = yrdf$Adj.Close[index+1]
      diff = val_index - val_next   #  diff between two adjacent values
      diff = diff/yrdf$Adj.Close[index+1] * 100.0
    }
    diff.vec<-c(diff.vec,diff) # append to vector of differences
  }
  return(diff.vec)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  forLoop = myForLoop()
  , vector = 100 * c(diff(yrdf$Adj.Close),NA) / c(yrdf$Adj.Close[2:nrow(yrdf)], NA)
)
```

gives:

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
 forLoop 74.238 78.184 82.06786 81.287 84.3740 104.190   100
  vector 20.193 21.718 23.91824 22.716 24.0535  80.754   100
```

Note that the `vector` approach takes about 30% of the time of the `for` loop. This gets more important as the size of the data increases:

```
set.seed(8675309)
yrdf <- data.frame(Adj.Close = rnorm(10000))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  forLoop = myForLoop()
  , vector = 100 * c(diff(yrdf$Adj.Close),NA) / c(yrdf$Adj.Close[2:nrow(yrdf)], NA)
)
```

gives

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr        min         lq        mean     median          uq        max neval
 forLoop 306883.977 315116.446 351183.7997 325211.743 361479.6835 545383.457   100
  vector    176.704    194.948    326.6135    219.512    236.9685   4989.051   100
```

Note that the difference in how these scale is *massive* -- the vector version takes less that 0.1% of the time to run. Here, this is likely because each call to `c` to add the new entry requires re-reading the full vector. A slight change can speed the for loop up a bit, but not get it all the way to the vector speed:

```
myForLoopAlt <- function(){
  numrows = nrow(yrdf)
  diff.vec = numeric(numrows)   # vector of differences
  for (index in 1:nrow(yrdf)) {   # yrdf is a data frame 
    if (index == numrows) {
      diff = NA  # because there is no entry "below" it
    } else {
      val_index = yrdf$Adj.Close[index] 
      val_next = yrdf$Adj.Close[index+1]
      diff = val_index - val_next   #  diff between two adjacent values
      diff = diff/yrdf$Adj.Close[index+1] * 100.0
    }
    diff.vec[index] <- diff # append to vector of differences
  }
  return(diff.vec)
}



microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  forLoop = myForLoop()
  , newLoop = myForLoopAlt()
  , vector = 100 * c(diff(yrdf$Adj.Close),NA) / c(yrdf$Adj.Close[2:nrow(yrdf)], NA)
)
```

gives

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr        min         lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
 forLoop 304751.250 315433.802 354605.5850 325944.9075 368584.2065 528732.259   100
 newLoop 168014.142 179579.984 186882.7679 181843.7465 188654.5325 318431.949   100
  vector    169.569    208.193    331.2579    219.9125    233.3115   2956.646   100
```

That saved half of the time off the `for` loop approach, but is still way, way slower than the vectorized solution.

Comment: Wow!   That's fantastic.    Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @whirlaway -- did that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it did.  And more.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
yrdf <- data.frame(Adj.Close = rnorm(100))
numrows <- length(yrdf$Adj.Close)
diff.vec <- c((yrdf$Adj.Close[1:(numrows-1)] / yrdf$Adj.Close[2:numrows] - 1) * 100, NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `lead` function from the `dplyr` package to get the result that you want.

```
library(dplyr)
yrdf <- data.frame(Adj.Close = rnorm(100))
(yrdf$Adj.Close/lead(yrdf$Adj.Close)-1)*100
```

The calculation has been simplified from (a-b)/b to a/b-1. This is a vectorized operation instead of a for loop.