# Slow `for` loop in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speed up the loop operation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r)

I have been using R for a few days now but I do find it extremelly slow (for loop takes for ever). I created simple script with basic computation and plotting of 1 graph. Does that sound normal to you?

I am using R studio. Do you know a better editor? I am not too impressed.