# R Code Taking Too Long To Run

Tags: r, for-loop, execute

I have the following code running and it's taking me a long time to run. How do I know if it's still doing its job or it got stuck somewhere.

```
noise4<-NULL;
for(i in 1:length(noise3))
{
    if(is.na(noise3[i])==TRUE)
    {
    next;
    }
    else
    {
    noise4<-c(noise4,noise3[i]);
    }
}
```

noise3 is a vector with 2418233 data points.

Comment: a for loop with 2 million iterations isn't going to show R in a very good light.

Comment: @David Heffernan: especially when you grow an object instead of pre-allocating.  @GTyler: it looks like you could just use `noise4 <- na.omit(noise3)`.

Comment: What do you mean? Is it just R not good with that many data points?

Comment: So will pre-allocating the size of the vector help? I think I know the resulting dimension of that vector.

Comment: @GTyler large for loops don't have good performance characteristics on R due to its interpreted nature. I believe that recent developments have improved things. All the same, you should always look for a version that avoids for loops if possible.

Comment: @GTyler Read this question and answer to see why `for` loops in this case are slow and how to avoid it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6502444/602276

Comment: @GTyler: R works fine with millions of data points.  But `for` loops are one of the least efficient ways of using R. Most R functions iterate through vectors naturally.  Have a look at this article: http://yihui.name/en/2010/10/on-the-gory-loops-in-r/ It explains how the R approach differs from "normal" programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just want to remove the NA values. Do it like this:

```
noise4 <- noise3[!is.na(noise3)]
```

This will be pretty much instant.

Or as Joshua suggests, a more readable alternative:

```
noise4 <- na.omit(noise3)
```

Your code was slow because:

1. It uses explicit loops which tend to be slow under the R interpreter.
2. You reallocate memory every iteration.

The memory reallocation is probably the biggest handicap to your code.

Comment: Or `noise4 <- na.omit(noise3)`.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to illustrate the benefits of pre-allocation, so I tried to run your code... but I killed it after ~5 minutes.  I recommend you use `noise4 <- na.omit(noise3)` as I said in my comments.  This code is solely for illustrative purposes.

```
# Create some random data
set.seed(21)
noise3 <- rnorm(2418233)
noise3[sample(2418233, 100)] <- NA

noise <- function(noise3) {
  # Pre-allocate
  noise4 <- vector("numeric", sum(!is.na(noise3)))
  for(i in seq_along(noise3)) {
    if(is.na(noise3[i])) {
      next
    } else {
      noise4[i] <- noise3[i]
    }
  }
}

system.time(noise(noise3)) # MUCH less than 5+ minutes
#    user  system elapsed 
#    9.50    0.44    9.94 

# Let's see what we gain from compiling
library(compiler)
cnoise <- cmpfun(noise)
system.time(cnoise(noise3))  # a decent reduction
#    user  system elapsed 
#    3.46    0.49    3.96
```

Comment: +1 I am starting to feel bad about having uncompiled functions.

Comment: @Iterator: don't feel bad.  They mostly help "looping" constructs where there are several repeated function calls.  You won't see much gain if you're already using vectorized functions.

Comment: @iterator Actually I think the difference between interpreted and compiled shows that the interpreter does a wonderful job. I am impressed.

Comment: @JoshuaUllrich: So, what you're saying is that these help on functions that are iterated a lot, eh?  Guess what my code does. :)  (Admittedly, I vectorize a lot.)

Comment: @David Heffernan: while the byte code compiler helps, moving the loop to C/C++ using the inline and/or Rcpp packages would provide near instantaneous results.

Comment: As long as you're being pedagogical why not show the timing for `na.omit(noise3)` as well ? (0.5 secs on my computer)

Answer (score 5):

The other answers have given you much, much better ways to do the task that you actually set out to achieve (removing `NA` values in your data), but an answer to the specific question you asked ("how do I know if R is actually working or if it has instead gotten stuck?") is to introduce some output (`cat`) statements in your loop, as follows:

```
rpt <- 10000  ## reporting interval
noise4<-NULL;
for(i in 1:length(noise3))
{
    if (i %% rpt == 0) cat(i,"\n")
    if(is.na(noise3[i])==TRUE)
    {
    next;
    }
    else
    {
    noise4<-c(noise4,noise3[i]);
    }
}
```

If you run this code you can immediately see that it slows down radically as it gets farther into the loop (a consequence of the failure to pre-allocate space) ...

Answer (score 3):

The others have all given correct ways to do the same problem, so that you needn't worry about speed.  @BenBolker also gave a good pointer regarding regular output.

A different thing to note is that if you find yourself in a loop, you can break out of it and find the value of `i`.  Assuming that re-starting from that value of `i` won't harm things, i.e. using that value twice won't be a problem, you can restart.  Or, you can just finish the job as the others have stated.

A separate trick is that if the loop is slow (and can't be vectorized or else you're not eager to break out of the loop), *AND* you don't have any reporting, you can still look for an external method to see if R is actually consuming cycles on your computer.  In Linux, the `top` command is your best bet.  On Windows, the task manager will do the trick (I prefer to use the SysInternals / Microsoft program Process Explorer).  'top' also exists on Macs, though I believe there are some other more popular tools.

One other word of advice: if you have a really long loop to run, I strongly encourage saving the results regularly.  I typically create a file with the a name like: `myPrefix_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.rdat` .  This way everything can go to hell and you can still start your loop where you left off.

I don't always iterate, but when I do, I use these tricks.  Stay speedy, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

For one case I've faced, updating all packages in use under R studio resolved the issue.