# R: looping to search for max of non-monotonic function

Tags: r, loops

Refer to the R code below. The function (someRfunction) operates on a vector and returns a scalar value. The data are pairs (x,y), where x and y are vectors of length n, which may be large.

I want to know the value of x* such that the result of someRfunction on y where {x>x*} is maximized. The function operates on y values and is non-monotonic in x*. I need to evaluate for all x* (i.e. each element of x).  Speed is not an issue if executed once, but the code would be executed many times in a simulation. Is there any way to make this code more efficient/faster?

```
### x and y are vectors of length n
### sort x and y such that they are ordered by descending x
xord <- x[order(-x)]
yord <- y[order(-x)]
maxf <- -99999
maxcut <- NA

for (i in 1:n) {
  ### yi is a subvector of y that corresponds to y[x>x{i}]
  ### where x{i} is the (n-i+1)th order statistic of x
  yi <- yord[1:(i-1)]
  fxi <- someRfunction(yi)
  if (fxi>maxf) {
    maxf <- fxi
    maxcut <- xord[i]
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Edit: let someRfunction(yi)=t.test(yi)$statistic.

Comment: Your code would likely benefit from significant vectorization.  Have a look here for some general suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8285793/636656

Comment: Why not use an [optimizer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can say anything more about the function, particularly whether it is smooth and whether its gradient can be determine, you will get a better answer. At the moment the only increase in speed will be modest due to the ability to pre-specify a vector to hold the results, omit that if-max clause and then use which.max() on the vector. You might want to look at the function `optimx` in package "optimx".

Comment: function is like t.test(yi)$statistic

Comment: You should be able to vectorize a `t.test$statistic`-like function, assuming it's something like `mean(vec)/sd(vec)` perhaps with a `length(vec)-1` factor applied.