# R: looping over large dataset takes a long time

Tags: r, loops, size

I need to apply the Mann Kendall trend test in R to a big number (about 1 million) of different-sized time series. I've created a .txt file like this:

```
1 2
1 4
1 5
2 4
2 55
3 2
3 4
3 5
3 4
3 55
...
```

Every number of the firs column identifies a particular time-series. To obtain the statistics I'm using this code:

```
library(Kendall)
a=read.table("to_r.txt")
numData=1017135

for (i in 1:numData){

s1=subset(a,a$V1==i)
m=MannKendall(s1$V2)
cat(m[[1]],"  ",m[[2]], "  ", m[[3]],"  ",m[[4]],"  ", m[[5]], "\n" ,   file="monotonic_trend_checking.txt",append=TRUE)
}
```

This approach works but the problem is that it is taking ages for computation. The time-series are 800 elements long at maximum (only few, the other are shorter) so I think that the main bottle-neck is in the loop. 
Can you suggest a faster approach?

Comment: Looping or not, reading a million text files will take a long time.  See this other question for ways to speed that up.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r/1728422

Comment: Also, this looks like a very parallelisable problem, so now might be a good time to look at one of the map/reduce packages. http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: General suggestions on speeding up R code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8474941/636656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very simple solution that splits your dataset into pieces and then applies `MannKendall` to each piece.

```
# example dataset
d <- data.frame(a=rnorm(1e6), b=rep(1:1000, each=1000))

mk <- lapply(split(d$a, d$b), MannKendall)
```

This takes about ten seconds on my machine, which is a moderately powerful desktop running Windows 7. The result is a list; here's the first component:

```
> mk[[1]]
tau = 0.0319, 2-sided pvalue =0.13133
```

If you want it all in a data frame:

```
mk <- do.call(rbind, mk)
```

Comment: This can be done in even less code using ddply from the plyr package, this combines the do.call and the lapply in one. Moreover, it provides support for parallel processing and provides a progress bar.

Comment: One thing to be wary of with plyr is that it doesn't cope well with large numbers of levels (because of its underlying reliance on data frames). While 1000 might still be okay, 10000 is into the no-go zone. So for simple tasks like this, I'd prefer to stick with base R.

Comment: I definitely agree, see also my reply to this question. For large numbers of levels I'd go for data.table, which is much faster even than the base R solution.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely take a look at data.table if you think that looping is the problem here. I recently wrote a blog post which compares several ways of looping in terms of performance:

http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/10/28/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/

The main message is that data.table performs really well when the number of unique id's (i.e. your number of timeseries) is very large.

Comment: Sorry for the shameless self promotion :)

Answer (score 1):

A big problem is that you're writing the results to a file for every single time series. File access takes time. It would be better to create a large data table with all of the results and then use `write.table()` once at the very end.

This, of course, assumes that you have enough RAM to hold the original data table and the new results table in memory, which probably won't be a huge problem.