# Performance of Matrix Multiplication varying across different R installations

Tags: r

I have access to two clusters where R has been installed. I have been coding and testing my stuff on one, all this time. When I moved my code to the new cluster, suddenly all matrix multiplications have become very slow. Here are some numbers:

```
Cluster-1:
> a <- matrix(0, nrow=2000, ncol=2000)
> b <- matrix(0, nrow=2000, ncol=2000)
> system.time(c <- a %*% b)
   user  system elapsed 
   0.07    0.03    0.10

Cluster-2:
> a <- matrix(0, nrow=2000, ncol=2000)
> b <- matrix(0, nrow=2000, ncol=2000)
> system.time(c <- a%*% b)
   user  system elapsed 
 13.682   0.014  13.695
```

Note that I am not using any sparse matrices.

Cluster-1 uses R version 2.12.1 and Cluster-2 uses R version 2.15.0. Is there any special library that the second cluster is missing? How do I find which one? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Adding more details about the clusters:

Cluster-1:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Cluster-2:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.iso885915       LC_NUMERIC=C                  
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.iso885915        LC_COLLATE=en_US.iso885915    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.iso885915    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.iso885915   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                     LC_NAME=C                     
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C                   LC_TELEPHONE=C                
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.iso885915 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C           

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be using a non-optimized BLAS.  See here for an example:
http://www.cybaea.net/Blogs/Data/Faster-R-through-better-BLAS.html

If so, it's an easy fix.

You can also try compiling and other tricks:
[Speed up the loop operation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r/8474941#8474941)

Comment: I would have thought that there is something else going on, 13sec for that operations is crazy slow even with the regular RBLAS. Could something else be running on the cluster?

Comment: @Hansi, On my machine (a couple years old), `c <- a%*% b` takes 12 seconds. However, @isEmpty, perhaps posting the result of `sessionInfo()` from both clusters would help.

Comment: I don't have root access to the cluster. So I can't install anything from the repo. Also, I saw somewhere in forums that compiling Atlas isn't a simple task. May be I should talk to the system administrator and see what can be done about it.

Comment: @Hansi Nothing else can be running on that cluster. I rent nodes exclusively for my use. Its not shared with anyone else.

Comment: @BenBarnes I have edited my question and added the sessionInfo information of both clusters.

Comment: @isEmpty: even without root access you can still try to build R and the optimized BLAS yourself (user-local; but of course you need a whole bunch of -dev versions of libraries). If your system runs a recent Ubuntu, installing OpenBLAS is so easy that your admin may do it if you ask really nicely: install (ubuntu) package libopenblas and enjoy. In case of Debian, have a look at Dirk's `gcbd` package (on CRAN).

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. Since the machine runs a RocksCluster OS, I compiled GotoBLAS and installed it. It was super simple.  Even though it is not as fast as ATLAS, it is faster than RBlas.