# Why this is so slow? (loop in a DF row vs. a standalone vector)

Tags: performance, r

I have a piece of code and total elapsed time is around 30 secs of which, the following code is around 27 secs. I narrowed the offending code to this:

```
d$dis300[i] <- h
```

So I change to this other piece and is now working really fast (as expected).

My question is why this is too slow against the second. The datos DF is around 7500x18 vars

First:  (27 sec elapsed)

```
d$dis300 <- 0
for (i in 1:netot) {
  h <- aaa[d$ent[i], d$dis[i]]
  if (h == 0) writeLines(sprintf("ERROR. ent:%i dis:%i", d$ent[i], d$dis[i]))
  d$dis300[i] <- h
}
```

Second:  (0.2 sec elapsed)

```
d$dis300 <- 0
for (i in 1:netot) {
  h <- aaa[d$ent[i], d$dis[i]]
  if (h == 0) writeLines(sprintf("ERROR. ent:%i dis:%i", d$ent[i], d$dis[i]))
  foo[i] <- h
}
d$foo <- foo
```

You can see both are the "same" but the offending one has this DF instead of a single vector.

Any comment is really appreciated. I came from another type of languages and this drove me nuts for a while. At least I have solution but I like to prevent this kind of issues in the future.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Just to clarify, the difference in speed between the two is 30sec vs 27sec, and you consider this a dramatic speed-up?

Comment: If @joran's relative timings are correct (and when is he wrong? :-) ), you'll get a lot better speed-ups by adopting these habits and techniques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r/8474941#8474941

Comment: @gsk3 Daily, according to my wife.

Comment: Seriously, I was going to suggest that the modest speed-up seen here was due to R's copy-on-assignment behavior: in one case copying a whole data frame, in the other only a vector, hence a small speed increase. And before you recoil in horror at the thought of copy-on-assignment, keep in mind that "coding smart" by following gsk3's advice means it usually isn't an issue.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the correct timing:  The whole script delays 30 sec  and the first par delays 27 sec.  If we compare the first against the second, the times are First: 27 sec, Second .2 sec. This is just an excerpt of the whole script.

Comment: @notuo But the first sentence of your question still comes across that the difference is 30sec vs 27sec. Can you edit that please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that `d$dis300[i] <- h` calls `$<-.data.frame`.

It's a rather complex function as you can see:

```
`$<-.data.frame`
```

You don't say what `foo` is, but if it is an atomic vector, the `$<-` function is implemented in C for speed.

Still, I hope you declare foo as follows:

```
foo <- numeric(netot)
```

This will ensure you don't need to reallocate the vector for each assignment in the loop:

```
foo <- 0 # BAD!
system.time( for(i in 1:5e4) foo[i] <- 0 ) # 4.40 secs
foo <- numeric(5e4) # Pre-allocate
system.time( for(i in 1:5e4) foo[i] <- 0 ) # 0.09 secs
```

Using the `*apply` family instead you don't worry about that:

```
d$foo <- vapply(1:netot, function(i, aaa, ent, dis) {
  h <- aaa[ent[i], dis[i]]
  if (h == 0) writeLines(sprintf("ERROR. ent:%i dis:%i", ent[i], dis[i]))
  h
}, numeric(1), aaa=aaa, ent=d$ent, dis=d$dis)
```

...here I also extracted `d$ent` and `d$dis` outside the loop which should improve things a bit too. Can't run it myself though since you didn't give reproducible data. But here's a similar example:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1)
system.time( vapply(1:1e6, function(i) d$x, numeric(1)) )         # 3.20 secs
system.time( vapply(1:1e6, function(i, x) x, numeric(1), x=d$x) ) # 0.56 secs
```

... but finally it seems it can all be reduced to (barring your error detection code):

```
d$foo <- aaa[cbind(d$ent, d$dis)]
```

Comment: +3 internets for seeing the one-liner hidden in the morass.

Comment: @Tommy: 10 beers for 120 reputation sounds like a very poor trade for you.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - True, but virtual beers are not as tasty as virtual reputation points :)

Comment: @Tommy: who said anything about virtual beers? Come to my town and I'll buy you at least one. FYI, you'll hit 10k tomorrow. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and lesson here Tommy. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Tommy's is the best answer. This was too big for comment so adding it as an answer...

This is how you can see the copies (of the whole of `DF`, as joran commented) yourself :

```
> DF = data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6)
> tracemem(DF)
[1] "<0x0000000003104800"
> for (i in 1:3) {DF$b[i] <- i; .Internal(inspect(DF))}
tracemem[0000000003104800 -> 000000000396EAD8]: 
tracemem[000000000396EAD8 -> 000000000396E4F0]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[000000000396E4F0 -> 000000000399CDC8]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
@000000000399CDC8 19 VECSXP g0c2 [OBJ,NAM(2),TR,ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
  @000000000399CD90 13 INTSXP g0c2 [] (len=3, tl=0) 1,2,3
  @000000000399CCE8 13 INTSXP g0c2 [] (len=3, tl=0) 1,5,6
ATTRIB: # .. snip ..

tracemem[000000000399CDC8 -> 000000000399CC40]: 
tracemem[000000000399CC40 -> 000000000399CAB8]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[000000000399CAB8 -> 000000000399C9A0]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
@000000000399C9A0 19 VECSXP g0c2 [OBJ,NAM(2),TR,ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
  @000000000399C968 13 INTSXP g0c2 [] (len=3, tl=0) 1,2,3
  @000000000399C888 13 INTSXP g0c2 [] (len=3, tl=0) 1,2,6
ATTRIB: # .. snip ..

tracemem[000000000399C9A0 -> 000000000399C7E0]: 
tracemem[000000000399C7E0 -> 000000000399C700]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[000000000399C700 -> 00000000039C78D8]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
@00000000039C78D8 19 VECSXP g0c2 [OBJ,NAM(2),TR,ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
  @00000000039C78A0 13 INTSXP g0c2 [] (len=3, tl=0) 1,2,3
  @0000000003E07890 13 INTSXP g0c2 [] (len=3, tl=0) 1,2,3
ATTRIB: # .. snip ..
> DF
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Each of those `tracemem[]` lines corresponds to a copy of the whole object. You can see the hex addresses of the `a` column vector changing each time, too, despite it not being modifed by the assignment to `b`.

AFAIK, without dropping into C code yourself, the only way (currently) in R to modify an item of a `data.frame` with no copy of any memory at all, is the `:=` operator and `set()` function, both in package [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/). There are [17 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5C%5Bdata.table%5C%5D%20reference) about assigning by reference using `:=` here on Stack Overflow.

But in this case Tommy's one liner is definitely best as you don't even need a loop at all.

Comment: Thank your for this lesson Matthew. Best regards.