# Rcpp pass by reference vs. by value

Tags: r, rcpp

I made a first stab at an Rcpp function via `inline` and it solved my speed problem (thanks Dirk!):
[Replace negative values by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275187/r-replacing-negative-values-by-zero/11275230#11275230)

The initial version looked like this:

```
library(inline)
cpp_if_src <- '
  Rcpp::NumericVector xa(a);
  int n_xa = xa.size();
  for(int i=0; i < n_xa; i++) {
    if(xa[i]<0) xa[i] = 0;
  }
  return xa;
'
cpp_if <- cxxfunction(signature(a="numeric"), cpp_if_src, plugin="Rcpp")
```

But when called `cpp_if(p)`, it overwrote `p` with the output, which was not as intended.  So I assumed it was passing by reference.

So I fixed it with the following version:

```
library(inline)
cpp_if_src <- '
  Rcpp::NumericVector xa(a);
  int n_xa = xa.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector xr(a);
  for(int i=0; i < n_xa; i++) {
    if(xr[i]<0) xr[i] = 0;
  }
  return xr;
'
cpp_if <- cxxfunction(signature(a="numeric"), cpp_if_src, plugin="Rcpp")
```

Which seemed to work.  But now the original version doesn't overwrite its input anymore when I re-load it into R (i.e. the same exact code now doesn't overwrite its input):

```
> cpp_if_src <- '
+   Rcpp::NumericVector xa(a);
+   int n_xa = xa.size();
+   for(int i=0; i < n_xa; i++) {
+     if(xa[i]<0) xa[i] = 0;
+   }
+   return xa;
+ '
> cpp_if <- cxxfunction(signature(a="numeric"), cpp_if_src, plugin="Rcpp")
> 
> p
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
> cpp_if(p)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
> p
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

I'm not the only one who has tried to replicate this behavior and found inconsistent results:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4357344#4357344

What's going on here?

Comment: Can you reformulate your question?  Do you, or don't you, want to overwrite?  Seems to me that version 2 achieves what it set out to do...  Also, there is a dedicated mailing list devoted to Rcpp where you are likely to get decent answers.

Comment: Tried to edit for clarity.  I do not want it to overwrite.  If this is non-obvious then I guess I should post to the mailing list, but didn't want to bother folks otherwise.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They key is 'proxy model' -- your `xa` really is the same memory location as your original object so you end up changing your original.

If you don't want that, you should do one thing:  (deep) copy using the `clone()` method, or maybe explicit creation of a new object into which the altered object gets written. Method two does *not* do that, you simply use two differently named variables which are both "pointers" (in the proxy model sense) to the original variable.

An additional complication, though, is in *implicit* cast and copy when you pass an int vector (from R) to a NumericVector type: that creates a copy, and then the original no longer gets altered.

Here is a more explicit example, similar to one I use in the tutorials or workshops:

```
library(inline)
f1 <- cxxfunction(signature(a="numeric"), plugin="Rcpp", body='
  Rcpp::NumericVector xa(a);
  int n = xa.size();
  for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    if(xa[i]<0) xa[i] = 0;
  }
  return xa;
')

f2 <- cxxfunction(signature(a="numeric"), plugin="Rcpp", body='
  Rcpp::NumericVector xa(a);
  int n = xa.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector xr(a);            // still points to a
  for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    if(xr[i]<0) xr[i] = 0;
  }
  return xr;
')

p <- seq(-2,2)
print(class(p))
print(cbind(f1(p), p))
print(cbind(f2(p), p))
p <- as.numeric(seq(-2,2))
print(class(p))
print(cbind(f1(p), p))
print(cbind(f2(p), p))
```

and this is what I see:

```
edd@max:~/svn/rcpp/pkg$ r /tmp/ari.r
Loading required package: methods
[1] "integer"
        p
[1,] 0 -2
[2,] 0 -1
[3,] 0  0
[4,] 1  1
[5,] 2  2
        p
[1,] 0 -2
[2,] 0 -1
[3,] 0  0
[4,] 1  1
[5,] 2  2
[1] "numeric"
       p
[1,] 0 0
[2,] 0 0
[3,] 0 0
[4,] 1 1
[5,] 2 2
       p
[1,] 0 0
[2,] 0 0
[3,] 0 0
[4,] 1 1
[5,] 2 2
edd@max:~/svn/rcpp/pkg$
```

So it really matters whether you pass int-to-float or float-to-float.

Comment: Thanks Dirk.  That tells me how I should have written the function (and I'll file it away for future use).  And I think the implicit cast and copy likely explains the seeming inconsistency.

Comment: It's a head-scratcher when you first encounter it, but yes, it does make sense.

Comment: Very interesting. One minor niggle for clarity: shouldn't p be redefined after each function call - particularly the second call to f1? Otherwise it's the altered p that's being fed into f2... right?

Comment: This is quite interesting. The only way to know this is through a debugger I guess (or you write the package like Dirk did). Is there a way to attach a debugger to Rcpp functions? I am thinking about a way like Visual Studio debugger attaches a dll, then when it is hit you can go into the code. .

Comment: @adam:  gcc/g++ are decades old, and so is their best friend gdb.