# Rcpp: Inconsistent behavior with proxy model

Tags: r, rcpp

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300048/rcpp-pass-by-reference-vs-by-value) discusses some issues with the proxy model for parameter passing in Rcpp. However, when I implemented this function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_size(NumericVector test){
  NumericVector test2(test);
  NumericVector test3 = NumericVector::create(1,1,1,1,1);
  test2 = test3;
  Rf_PrintValue(test);
}
```

We get:

```
> temp = c(2,2,2,2)
> test_size(temp)
[1] 2 2 2 2
```

So the problem is that the previous post and this  [book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461468677) say that in this case `test2` should be a pointer to the underlying `SEXP` object from `R`. However, when we assigned `test2 = test3`, this didn't apply to `test` because the `test` `NumericVector` remained unchanged.

**updated**

I am adding an example where I think assignment isn't working as Dirk suggested, but of course I could be misunderstanding the problem.

So suppose I have the following function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector testing(){
  NumericMatrix mat(3,3);
  mat.row(0) = NumericVector::create(1,1,1);
  mat.row(1) = NumericVector::create(1,1,1);
  mat.row(2) = NumericVector::create(2,2,2);
  NumericVector test;
  NumericVector test2;
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.nrow(); i++){
    test = mat.row(i);
    if (test[0] == 1){
      test2 = test;
    }
  }
  return test2;
}
```

This function is supposed to output `1,1,1`, but instead it outputs `2,2,2`. However when I replace `test2 = test` with `test2 = clone(test)` then I get the correct output. So I was wondering why am I getting this behavior even though this is just assignment as Dirk suggested?

Answer (score 2):

I gets easier when you look at all three as in the modified program below:

```
R> testvecs(c(2,2,2,2))
$test
[1] 2 2 2 2

$test2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

$test3
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

R>
```

where the (now complete) code is

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List testvecs(NumericVector test){
  NumericVector test2(test);
  NumericVector test3 = NumericVector::create(1,1,1,1,1);
  test2 = test3;
  return List::create(Named("test") = test,
                      Named("test2") = test2,
                      Named("test3") = test3);
}

/*** R
testvecs(c(2,2,2,2))
*/
```

So:

- `test` is incoming and unaltered, no surprise on the outcome
- `test2` is created and *then overwritten*
- `test3` is freshly created, and comes out as expected
- `test2` is assigned to be the same as `test3`, and it is.

I see no inconsistency here.

Comment: but `test2` is pointing to `test`, so I am expecting that when `test2` gets modified, then `test` also gets modified.

Comment: `test2[1] = 42` would do what you expect but your `test2 = test3;` undoes the earlier creation of `test2`.  That's just how assignment works.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I am still having problems with assignments. Please see my updated question for a new example of a problem I am encountering.

Comment: just a friendly reminder that I updated the question. I am really trying to understand what is going on here. thanks again Sir.