# Strange behavior of C++/Rcpp::NumericVector: Updating values of a vector in C++ causes updates in R in different vector

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I use Rcpp to outsource a nested loop from R (the time improvements are huge!). But I have encountered a strange behavior now. The first function `testrun` takes as argument a matrix `X` and loops over every row of that matrix. The row is passed to another function `testfun` which runs another loop and performs some computations. For every computation a value is returned and stored and eventually returned by the `testrun` function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector testrun(Rcpp::NumericMatrix X, Rcpp::NumericVector wal)
{
    Rcpp::NumericVector c;

    for(int i = 0; i != X.rows(); ++i)
    {
        c.push_back(testfun(X.row(i), wal));
    }

    return c;
}
```

The function `testfun` works on every row of `X`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int testfun(Rcpp::NumericVector x, Rcpp::NumericVector val)
{   
    int t = 0;
    Rcpp::NumericVector val2 = val;

    while(1)
    {
        std::vector<double> a;
        std::vector<double> b;

        for(int j = 0; j != x.length(); ++j)
        {
            a.push_back(std::sin(x.at(j)));
            b.push_back(R::rnorm(1.0, 1.0));
        }

        for(int j = 0; j != x.length(); ++j)
        {   
            if(a.at(j) > b.at(j))
            {
                val2[j] = 1;   
            }
        }

        if(Rcpp::sum(val2) == x.length())
        {
            break;
        }

        ++t;
    }

    return t;
}
```

The second argument of `testrun` and `testfun` is a vector of "modifier" values which are used in the computation. The values of this vector get updated depending on the computation and thus serve as exit condition for the loop.

I call `testrun` from R

```
X = expand.grid(replicate(2, list(seq(-3,3,length.out=10))))
wal = c(0.4, 0.2)

testrun(X, wal)
```

Both values in `wal` are < 1. But apparently the values in `wal` (in R!) get updated when updating `val2` in `testfun`. That is, the first time the exit condition is satisfied, it is satisfied for all subsequent steps. Why is this the case? And how do I prevent this behavior? If I use a single `double` for `wal` (and `val2`) it works as intended.

Comment: This is pretty well documented behavior, but also a common thing for newcomers to trip up on. The short answer is change the line `Rcpp::NumericVector val2 = val;` to `Rcpp::NumericVector val2 = Rcpp::clone(val);`. The longer answer (as to *why*), is covered in several places, such as [this Stack Overflow answer by Dirk Eddelbuettel himself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300707/8386140)

Comment: See the Rcpp FAQ; what you pass are internal `SEXP` objects where P stands for pointer.  So `val2` alters `val` as they are both pointers to the same memory.  If you want a distinct deep copy, make one.

Comment: Also don't use `push_back()` on Rcpp vectors -- very inefficient for similar reasons of  R implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In fact, I wasn't aware of this (but as duckmayr spotted: I am a newbie to Rcpp and advanced in C++ neither – the huge performance improvements made me use it and it's great :-D) thank you!