# Replacing numeric values to string in DataFrame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a query regarding replacing values in DataFrame. I have a dataset which consists of negative, positive, and zero values.
I want to replace all the negatives with '*', zeros with '_' and positives with '**'.

Data is something like this:

```
    C1     C2    C3    C4
R1 1.2    0.0   -0.2   3
R2 -0.5   3.4    0.0   4
R3 0.5    -4    -2.8   0.0
```

Result should come like:

```
     C1    C2    C3   C4
R1   **    _     *    **
R2   *     **    _    **
R3   **    *    *      _
```

I tried a few options, given here [Replace negative values by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275187/replace-negative-values-by-zero)
Unfortunately, once I replace a numeric DataFrame, then I cannot put any logical operation on it. So I Could just replace one of the values.

If anyone has an idea how to sort, please suggest.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
import numpy as np

out = np.sign(df).replace({-1: '*', 0: '_', 1: '**'})
```

Output:

```
    C1  C2 C3  C4
R1  **   _  *  **
R2   *  **  _  **
R3  **   *  *   _
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with DataFrame constructor if performance is important:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.select([df.gt(0), df.lt(0)], ['**','*'], '_'), 
                   index=df.index, 
                   columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
    C1  C2 C3  C4
R1  **   _  *  **
R2   *  **  _  **
R3  **   *  *   _
```

Or if possible rewrite original values:

```
df[:] = np.select([df.gt(0), df.lt(0)], ['**','*'], '_')
print (df)
    C1  C2 C3  C4
R1  **   _  *  **
R2   *  **  _  **
R3  **   *  *   _
```

Testing in 1k rows, 1k columns:

```
np.random.seed(1230)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(1000,1000))).sub(.5).mask(lambda x: x.gt(.2), 0)

In [200]: %timeit np.sign(df).replace({-1: '*', 0: '_', 1: '**'})
206 ms ± 1.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [201]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.select([df.gt(0), df.lt(0)], ['**','*'], '_'),  
                               index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
52.2 ms ± 203 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```