# Trying to use C files in R package to implement in a standalone C program

Tags: r, calloc

I recently downloaded this R package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/energy/index.html) and was able to successfully install it and run it on my system and calculate distance correlation.

The problem is for loops in R takes forever and I am an R newbie. The source code is actually written in some files in C, which R uses to evaluate. I have these two files in `src` folder in the package `utilities.c` and `dcov.c` Which has functions I need to implement.

I tried to compile `dcov.c` which uses `rmath.h` and `r.h` apparently and I got a bunch of errors about Calloc/Free used in the program.

Any idea how I can just compile the C programs?

Comment: Probably substantially easier to [speed up your loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2908822/636656) than to try reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The thing is I am basically calculating a correlation coefficient matrix like cor(M) would do. I have to do it a column against every other column in M. I am not at all confident that can be done in R. I ve been reading up a lot on loop optimization in R.

Comment: Basically all i am trying to do is :

`for( i in 1:n){
  for(j in (i+1):n) {
  dcormat[i,j]<-dcor(M[,i],M[,j])
  }
 } `

If there is some way of speeding this up, that I am missing, that would be great. dcor is the function in the package. M is the input matrix and dcormat is just a square matrix with correlation coefficients.

Comment: Loops are slow.  Vectorization is fast.  See the link in my previous comments for suggestions, and post your question if you still need help.  You almost certainly don't need C to make that algorithm fast.

Comment: FOr the past 2 days I ve been trying to vectorise the code snippet from my previous comment. I am drawing blanks. Any ideas? The problem is that dcor doesnt accept matrix inputs. It accepts 2 vectors and and computes the coefficient. I am not sure how to change the  functionality so  that i can vectorise my inputs.  any help will be greatly appreciated.