# Why is this for loop taking so long? 10+ min. in R

Tags: r, for-loop

```
res["DATA_FLAG"] <- NA

for(i in remove.res) {
  res$DATA_FLAG[i] <- "BADDATA"
}
```

res is just a data frame where I add a column DATA_FLAG

remove.res is just a vector of numbers which correspond to rows in which the data frame "res" I want to add the flag BADDATA

Comment: How big is the data frame? How long is `remove.res`? Also, you should simply do `res$DATA_FLAG[remove.res] = "BADDATA"`

Comment: Have you looked at these? http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r/