# How do I speed up text searches in R?

Tags: r, optimization

I have a large text vector I would like to search for a particular character or phrase.  Regular expressions are taking forever.  How do I search it quickly?

Sample data:

```
R <- 10^7
garbage <- replicate( R, paste0(sample(c(letters[1:5]," "),10,replace=TRUE),collapse="") )
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do need regular expressions, you can generally get a performance increase over the default regular expression engine by using the PCRE library (by setting `perl=TRUE`).  There are other performance tips in `?grep`:

> **Performance considerations:**
>
> If you are doing a lot of regular expression matching, including on
>   very long strings, you will want to consider the options used.
>   Generally PCRE will be faster than the default regular expression
>   engine, and ‘fixed = TRUE’ faster still (especially when each pattern
>   is matched only a few times).
>
> If you are working in a single-byte locale and have marked UTF-8
>   strings that are representable in that locale, convert them first as
>   just one UTF-8 string will force all the matching to be done in
>   Unicode, which attracts a penalty of around 3x for the default POSIX
>   1003.2 mode.
>
> If you can make use of ‘useBytes = TRUE’, the strings will not be
>   checked before matching, and the actual matching will be faster. Often
>   byte-based matching suffices in a UTF-8 locale since byte patterns of
>   one character never match part of another.

Comment: Cool.  Presumably there are tricks with factors that could work as well if you have lots of repeated vectors....

Comment: The perl flag made a major positive performance impact. Nearly instantaneous in my case on a 43 MB data frame. Previously the time was around 2-3 seconds per. Since I was making an app that needs live time response, this was the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

There's no need for regular expressions here, and their power comes with a computational cost.

You can turn off regular expression parsing in any of the regex functions in R with the `,fixed=TRUE` argument.  Speed gains result:

```
library(microbenchmark)
m <- microbenchmark( 
    grep( " ", garbage, fixed=TRUE ),
    grep( " ", garbage )
)
m
Unit: milliseconds
                             expr       min        lq   median        uq      max neval
 grep(" ", garbage, fixed = TRUE)  491.5634  497.1309  499.109  503.3009 1128.643   100
               grep(" ", garbage) 1786.8500 1801.9837 1810.294 1825.2755 3620.346   100
```