# Regex Matching Negative values

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to create some simple and easy to write content-clusters with multiple regexes.

Imagine a list of strings: c("a","b","ac")
The groups I need to define are "All: a's" and "All: b's". So the values "a" and "ac" are "A" and "b" is "B".

```
myDF$contentGroup <- sub(".*a.*", "A", myDF$stringList)
```

However this will result in a column within my dataframe "contentGroup" which contains the value of "stringList" if no match occured. So if I do the same line of code with "B" it will overwrite the "A"s.

```
myDF$contentGroup <- sub(".*b.*", "B", myDF$stringList)
```

I just cant figure out how to do simple clustering in a single line of code. Making it as simple as possible.

Comment: `grepl()`  shall do the job. `x <-  c("a","b","ac"); x[grepl("a|A",x)]` is this you want?

Comment: `x[grep('a', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 'A'; x[grep('b', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 'B'`

Comment: ^ Don't forget to add `fixed = TRUE` in those statmentsfor ~X10 boost in performance

Comment: @DavidArenburg, why does `fixed` improve the speed?

Comment: @joel.wilson [here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458724/how-do-i-speed-up-text-searches-in-r) - Short answer, it disables regex parsing

Comment: @Sotos thanks, I have been through thatanswer, but i never understood 'WHY' fixed=TRUE makes it faster. Could you add a brief reasoning on that please? Thanks

Comment: @joel.wilson Because parsing regex is much more complicated than finding exact matches. The rule of thumb is that if `sub` or `grep` don't have any expression in their `pattern` argument, rather a normal string, always use `fixed = TRUE`

Comment: @DavidArenburg got it.. thanks.. Sotos thanks buddy!

Comment: Someone needs to move the answer from comments to an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` to match 'a' and 'b', and replace as follows,

```
x[grep('a', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 'A'
x[grep('b', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 'B'

x
#[1] "A" "B" "A"
```