# linear model in for loop; using apply function?

Tags: r

Is there any way to make the following algorithm faster, such as using an apply function?

```
    set.seed(1)
    n=1000

    y=rnorm(n)
    x1=rnorm(n)
    x2=rnorm(n)

    lm.ft=function(y,x1,x2)
      return(lm(y~x1+x2)$coef)

    res=list();
    for(i in 1:n){
      x1.bar=x1-x1[i]
      x2.bar=x2-x2[i]
      res[[i]]=lm.ft(y,x1.bar,x2.bar)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lm.fit` instead of `lm`:

```
fun1 <- function() {
  res=list();
  for(i in 1:n){
    x1.bar=x1-x1[i]
    x2.bar=x2-x2[i]
    res[[i]]=lm.ft(y,x1.bar,x2.bar)
  }
  res
}

lm.ft2 <- function(y,x1,x2) lm.fit(cbind(1,x1,x2), y)$coef

fun2 <- function() {
  res2 <- sapply(seq_along(y), function(i, x1, x2, y) {
    x1.bar=x1-x1[i]
    x2.bar=x2-x2[i]
    lm.ft2(y,x1.bar,x2.bar)
  }, x1=x1, x2=x2, y=y)
  res2
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(res <- fun1(), res2 <- fun2(), times=10)

#Unit: milliseconds
#         expr        min         lq    median        uq       max neval
#res <- fun1() 147.776069 149.580443 152.64378 159.53053 166.06834    10
#res <- fun2()   8.760102   9.004934  10.34582  10.58757  13.86649    10


all.equal(
  unname(t(res2)),
  unname(do.call(rbind,res))
)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: It seems most of the speed improvement is from using lm.fit. Is there any other way to reduce the speed from the FOR loop? In fact, I need to use double for loops.

Comment: I doubt that you need a double `for` loop. However, `for` loops are actually pretty fast in R (and `lapply` and friends are not faster). What you do inside the loop usually is the time consuming part. The best speed-up you can achieve by using vectorized functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r/8474941#8474941