# Looking up values in data.frame for given rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset (sample). Obviously, the real data set that I am using is much larger:

```
gvkey     tic  stko   year
001689   AEP1     1   2011
017096    BA3     1   2011
001440    AEP     0   2011
002285     BA     0   2011
001689   AEP1     1   2012
017096    BA3     1   2012
001440    AEP     0   2012
002285     BA     0   2012
```

Here is the code to generate the data:

```
dat <- data.frame(gvkey=c("001689", "017096", "001440", "002285"), tic=c("AEP1", "BA3", "AEP", "BA"), stko=c(1, 1, 0, 0), year=c(2011,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012))
```

Here is what I would like to do: Each row represents a year-firm pair with `tic` being the firm ticker. Firms where `stko` equals `1` are subsidiaries and share the same `tic` as their parent company, but have a number attached to the ticker, e.g. `AEP1` belongs to `AEP`. Basically, I would like to create a new variable `parent`, which indicates for each subsidiary (row with `stko=1`) the `gvkey` of the parent company. And I would like to do that for each year. The final data set should look like this:

```
gvkey     tic  stko   year  parent
001689   AEP1     1   2011  001440
017096    BA3     1   2011  002285
001440    AEP     0   2011  
002285     BA     0   2011  
001689   AEP1     1   2012  001440
017096    BA3     1   2012  002285
001440    AEP     0   2012  
002285     BA     0   2012
```

Now, my initial approach would be to write a couple of `for` loops that for a given year iterate over the rows. Whenever, `stko=1`, then extract the part of the ticker without the number at the end (e.g. for row one `AEP`) and find the row with this exact ticker in the given year (e.g. row 3 for year 2011) and copy the `gvkey` of that row to the initial observation with `stko=1`.

However, this procedure will be really slow given the size of my data set. I would be grateful if anyone can think of a faster and easier approach.

Many thanks!!

Using my main data set, the output for `dput(droplevels(head(dat)))` is:

```
structure(list(gvkey = c("176017", "128663", "61586", "278120", 
"14062", "285313"), datadate = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("31dec2010", "31dec2011", "31dec2012", "31dec2013"
), class = "factor"), fyear = c(2013, 2013, 2010, 2012, 2011, 
2010), indfmt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "INDL", class = "factor"), 
consol = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "C", class = "factor"), 
popsrc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "D", class = "factor"), 
datafmt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "STD", class = "factor"), 
tic = c("ATHX", "SQNM", "IMH", "FNLIF", "CCDBF", "BSBR"), 
cusip = structure(c(1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("04744L106", 
"05967A107", "124900309", "33564P103", "45254P508", "817337405"
), class = "factor"), conm = structure(c(1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("ATHERSYS INC", "BANCO SANTANDER BRASIL  -ADR", 
"CCL INDUSTRIES  -CL B", "FIRST NATIONAL FINL CORP", "IMPAC MORTGAGE HOLDINGS INC", 
"SEQUENOM INC"), class = "factor"), curcd = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("CAD", "USD"), class = "factor"), 
costat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
stko = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("gvkey", "datadate", 
"fyear", "indfmt", "consol", "popsrc", "datafmt", "tic", "cusip", 
"conm", "curcd", "costat", "stko"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option with `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(tic2 = gsub("[0-9]", "", tic)) %>%
  group_by(tic2, year) %>%
  mutate(parent = ifelse(stko == 1, as.character(gvkey[stko == 0][1]), "")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-tic2)


#Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
#
#   gvkey  tic stko year parent
#1 001689 AEP1    1 2011 001440
#2 017096  BA3    1 2011 002285
#3 001440  AEP    0 2011       
#4 002285   BA    0 2011       
#5 001689 AEP1    1 2012 001440
#6 017096  BA3    1 2012 002285
#7 001440  AEP    0 2012       
#8 002285   BA    0 2012
```

Edit: if there can be companies without a matching parent, try this code:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(tic2 = gsub("[0-9]", "", tic)) %>%
  group_by(tic2, year) %>%
  mutate(parent = ifelse(stko == 1 & sum(stko == 0) > 0, 
                         as.character(gvkey[stko == 0][1]), "")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-tic2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a working solution, but you're looking for speed. For that, you're going to want to use subsetting and vectorized operations instead of loops (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r)). I'd also find a solution using `dplyr` or `data.table` because they're both dramatically faster than base R.

Here's my attempt at a solution based on those ideas.

```
require(dplyr)

parents <- dat %>%
  filter(stko == 0) %>%
  select(tic, gvkey) %>%
  unique(.)
rownames(parents) <- parents$tic

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(
    parentTic = sub("[1-9]$", "", tic),
    parentGvkey = parents[parentTic, "gvkey"])
```

Comment: This one works well for my data set (I have additional variables that I didn't include in the sample in my post). I just substituted the `sub()` with the `gsub()` function in order to make it work for subsidiary tickers that have multiple digit numbers in the end.

Comment: Ideally, it should take care of the years. However, I haven't manage to get the two other solutions working for my main data set.

Comment: What do you mean in the OP: "And I would like to do that for each year." All ```gvkey``` for a parent company are identical between years, at least in the provided data frame.

Comment: Yes, in the sample the companies are identical among the years, however, this is not usually the case in my main data set.

Comment: It would have been good to have that detail in your sample data set. In case you haven't read it already, this post on reproducible examples is essential reading on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly straightforward exercise in the `base::merge` function

```
 rbind(transform(dat[dat$stko == 0, ], parent = ''),
   merge(
     transform(dat[dat$stko != 0, ], tic.parent = gsub('[0-9]', '', tic)),
     unique(transform(dat[dat$stko == 0, ], parent = gvkey)[, c('tic', 'parent', 'year')]),
     by.x = c('tic.parent', 'year'), by.y = c('tic', 'year')
   )[, -1]
 )

 #     gvkey  tic stko year parent
 # 3  001440  AEP    0 2011
 # 4  002285   BA    0 2011
 # 7  001440  AEP    0 2012
 # 8  002285   BA    0 2012
 # 5  001689 AEP1    1 2011 001440
 # 6  001689 AEP1    1 2012 001440
 # 71 017096  BA3    1 2011 002285
 # 81 017096  BA3    1 2012 002285
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error. I tried to come up with a solution with `dplyr` but @beginneR beat me fair and square.