# How could I speed up my R code?

Tags: r, performance, loops, nested-loops, multicore

---

### Disclaimer

Hello everyone! I recently started programming in R. My codes are working just fine, but in terms of speed some of them are taking way too long to put to good use. I hope someone can help me making this code run faster either by optimising the code, or with the use of one of the multicore packages.

---

### About the code

I have large datasets containing about 15000 numeric data each. The code takes two parameters (p, n) where p >= n, and make subsets of the data. It applies the zyp.yuepilon function (from the zyp package) to each row of the subsets. Then the parameter n is used to apply the same function on an n sized subset.

Problem is I run this code in a nested for loop: p in 10:40 and n in 10:40 so it takes an eternity to get the results, and it's just one dataset among many others.

```
sp <- function(p, n){
  library(zyp)

  data <- runif(15000, 1, 4)
  lower <- seq(80 - p + 1, by=1, length.out=length(data)-81)
  upper <- lower + p - 1

  subsets <- matrix(nrow=length(lower), ncol=p)
  for(j in 1:length(lower)){
    subsets[j, ] = data[lower[j] : upper[j]]
  }

  ret <- apply(subsets, 1, zyp.yuepilon)

  subset_n <- subsets[, 1:n]
  ret2 <- apply(subset_n, 1, zyp.yuepilon)
  return(list(ret, ret2))
}
```

Benchmark results in seconds:

```
expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
sp(7, 6) 92.77266 94.24901 94.53346 95.10363 95.64914    10
```

Comment: The first step if code is too slow is profiling. See `help("Rprof")`.

Comment: ^ Yes, you need to find out where the time is spent to avoid premature optimization.

Comment: However, I suspect that `zyp.yuepilon` is your bottleneck. Write a faster implementation or use parallelization.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing working code; it's a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I really appreciate them. I used profiling, and zyp.yuepilon is the bottleneck as Roland wrote.

I tried to use the snowfall package, but didn't really get faster.

It really is off-topic, thanks for pointing it out. I will pay more attention in the future.

Comment: The author of the original post does clearly state that they "recently started programming in R". Perhaps the question could be phrased more accurately, by someone with more experience, as: "what is the best, or alternative, loop methods when calling a non-optimised function. I've tried using `apply`, here is my code." Not sure what exactly is off-topic here - perhaps remove the zyp library, and provide a generic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a series of comments, rather than an answer.

Looking at the `zyp.yuepilon` function body, by calling the function without parenthesis in a R session, you see that this function, and the function `zyp.sen` are written in plain R code (as opposed to compiled code).

The biggest speed-up is likely attained by using the `Rcpp` package which facilitates calling (compiled) C++ code within R. In fact, there is a small linear model example here [Fast LM model using Rcpp/RcppArmadillo](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/fast-linear-model-with-armadillo/).

I would be inclined to rewrite the two functions `zyp.yuepilon` and `zyp.sen` in C++, using `Rcpp`, including the loop over subset vectors (for which you are currently using `apply` to do).

For general R speed-up issues see this question [R loop performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r), as well as the R package `plyr`, which may provide an entry point for taking a map-reduce type of approach to your problem.

If you want to steer clear of C++, then a series of micro-optimisations would be your quickest win. To speed up the `apply` aspect of your code, you could use something like this

```
library(doParallel)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(zyp)

cl<-makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

sp_1<-function(p=7, n=6){
N_ob=15000; 
off_set=81; 
N_ob_o=N_ob-off_set; 

am<-matrix(runif(N_ob*p),ncol=p); 
subsets<-am[-(1:off_set),];
ret=matrix(unlist( foreach(i=1:N_ob_o) %dopar% zyp::zyp.yuepilon(subsets[i,]),use.names=FALSE),ncol=11, byrow=TRUE);

subset_n <- subsets[, 1:n]
ret2=matrix(unlist( foreach(i=1:N_ob_o) %dopar% zyp::zyp.yuepilon(subset_n[i,]),use.names=FALSE),nrow=11);
return(list(ret, ret2))
}

sp<-function(p=7, n=6){

data <- runif(15000, 1, 4)
lower <- seq(80 - p + 1, by=1, length.out=length(data)-81)
upper <- lower + p - 1

subsets <- matrix(nrow=length(lower), ncol=p)
for(j in 1:length(lower)){
subsets[j, ] = data[lower[j] : upper[j]]
}

ret <- apply(subsets, 1, zyp.yuepilon)

subset_n <- subsets[, 1:n]
ret2 <- apply(subset_n, 1, zyp.yuepilon)
return(list(ret, ret2))
}

system.time(sp_1())
system.time(sp())
```

This gives me a speed-up of around a factor of 2. But this will depend on your platform, etc. Check out the help files for the functions and packages above, and tune the number of clusters using `makeCluster` to see what works best for your platform (in the absence of any information about your particular set-up).

Another route might be to make use of the byte-code compiler via `library(compiler)` to see if the various functions can be optimised, this way.

```
library(compiler)
enableJit(3);
zyp_comp<-cmpfun(zyp.yuepilon);
```