# Calculations by group between two data.tables in R

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I presented a similar post earlier this week ([For loop vectorization)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219450/increase-for-loop-efficiency-using-vectorization-in-r/26225735#26225735) and am very appreciative of the answer provided. The current question follows up on the use of the `data.table` package and its ability to cycle through the groups of two data.tables to perform a specific calculation.

**Background:**

I recreated the data following the same formatting as before and included the answer provided by @jlhoward. In this example, I have `dt1` which consists of subjects and their measured values (`values`) grouped by `group` and `time`. Additionally, `dt2` has the measured values of only one subject which happens to be a reference with some known status.

The `group_mean` function, when applied, cycles through each subject's measured values by `group` and `time` and compares them to the measured values of the reference subject in `dt2`. The `p_value` will then tell us how different/similar the variance of the measured values are between each other.

```
> library(data.table)
> library(lawstat)

> dt1 <- data.table(group = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], c(20,20,20))),
+                   time = factor(rep(1:5, 12)),
+                   values = runif(60, min = 0, max = 1),
+                   key = c("group", "time"))
> dt2 <- data.table(group = factor(rep(LETTERS[4], 15)),
+                   values = runif(15, min = 0, max = 1),
+                   key = "group")

#Provided by @jlhoward#
> group_mean <- function(values)
+ {
+     example <- data.table(group = rep(c("T", "C"), c(length(values), nrow(dt2))),
+                           values = c(values, dt2$values))
+     with(example, levene.test(values, group)$p.value)
+ }

> dt1[, list(p_value = group_mean(values)), by = c("group", "time")]
    group time     p_value
 1:     A    1 0.009812081
 2:     A    2 0.840368463
 3:     A    3 0.883976812
 4:     A    4 0.961928210
 5:     A    5 0.132638244
 6:     B    1 0.637280622
 7:     B    2 0.867169067
 8:     B    3 0.702991461
 9:     B    4 0.899523194
10:     B    5 0.570103537
11:     C    1 0.100202309
12:     C    2 0.287019659
13:     C    3 0.617098238
14:     C    4 0.069866914
15:     C    5 0.103481549
```

**Problem:**

There may be a point in time where the status of other subjects is determined and their measured values are consequently added to `dt2` (represented with the following code for `dt3`).

```
> dt3 <- data.table(group = factor(rep(LETTERS[4:6], c(15,15,15))),
+                   values = c(dt2$values, runif(30, min = 0, max = 1)),
+                   key = "group")
```

**Question:**

**How could I modify the `group_mean` function as to perform this variance test on the measured values between each subject in `dt1` (by `group` and `time`) and each subject in `dt3` (by `group`)?**

While I want to subset each subject from `dt3` with a `for` loop, I am attempting to better understand `data.table` and its syntax. An example of the desired output is below with the `p_value` intentionally left blank.

```
    group time ref_group p_value
 1:     A    1         D        
 2:     A    2         D        
 3:     A    3         D        
 4:     A    4         D        
 5:     A    5         D        
 6:     A    1         E        
 7:     A    2         E        
 8:     A    3         E        
 9:     A    4         E        
10:     A    5         E        
11:     A    1         F        
12:     A    2         F        
13:     A    3         F        
14:     A    4         F        
15:     A    5         F        
16:     B    1         D        
17:     B    2         D        
18:     B    3         D        
19:     B    4         D        
20:     B    5         D        
21:     B    1         E        
22:     B    2         E        
23:     B    3         E        
24:     B    4         E        
25:     B    5         E        
26:     B    1         F        
27:     B    2         F        
28:     B    3         F        
29:     B    4         F        
30:     B    5         F        
31:     C    1         D        
32:     C    2         D        
33:     C    3         D        
34:     C    4         D        
35:     C    5         D        
36:     C    1         E        
37:     C    2         E        
38:     C    3         E        
39:     C    4         E        
40:     C    5         E        
41:     C    1         F        
42:     C    2         F        
43:     C    3         F        
44:     C    4         F        
45:     C    5         F
```

As always, thank you for your time and input/comments.