# looping through list with data frames in r

Tags: r, list

i have a list with 205 different data.frames in it. Each data frame contains **205** columns and **150** rows

i want to loop through each data frame and select a set of rows and save it in another list.

the list containing 205 data frames looks like this but with different row names and colnames each in each data frame

```
list1[[1]]

         S48      S55      S58      S63      S81      S82              
 201501 3.882404 4.431433 4.208048 3.804576 4.619146 4.491193           
 5909   5.073869 6.164607 4.795546 4.344407 4.673163 5.185577 
 1056   6.099640 5.761811 5.653437 4.442167 6.943914 8.2185407
 90993  6.767227 6.744791 5.995674 6.064480 6.599200 6.461070 
 51268  5.849200 5.049686 4.806815 4.115414 5.216890 5.277743
```

what i eventuallly want is an output like this for each data frame in list1 (but until i got subsets of 150 rows)

```
         S48      S55      S58      S63      S81      S82              
 201501 3.882404 4.431433 4.208048 3.804576 4.619146 4.491193           
 5909   5.073869 6.164607 4.795546 4.344407 4.673163 5.185577 

         S48      S55      S58      S63      S81      S82              
 201501 3.882404 4.431433 4.208048 3.804576 4.619146 4.491193           
 5909   5.073869 6.164607 4.795546 4.344407 4.673163 5.185577 
 1056   6.099640 5.761811 5.653437 4.442167 6.943914 8.2185407

         S48      S55      S58      S63      S81      S82              
 201501 3.882404 4.431433 4.208048 3.804576 4.619146 4.491193           
 5909   5.073869 6.164607 4.795546 4.344407 4.673163 5.185577 
 1056   6.099640 5.761811 5.653437 4.442167 6.943914 8.2185407
 90993  6.767227 6.744791 5.995674 6.064480 6.599200 6.461070 

         S48      S55      S58      S63      S81      S82              
 201501 3.882404 4.431433 4.208048 3.804576 4.619146 4.491193           
 5909   5.073869 6.164607 4.795546 4.344407 4.673163 5.185577 
 1056   6.099640 5.761811 5.653437 4.442167 6.943914 8.2185407
 90993  6.767227 6.744791 5.995674 6.064480 6.599200 6.461070 
 51268  5.849200 5.049686 4.806815 4.115414 5.216890 5.277743
```

etc. etc.

i want to save all of these data frames in a list
so eventually i will have 205 lists (containing a list from subsets of data frames like the data above) and i want to save those 205 list together in one list

here's the code what i have

```
newlist = list()

for (i in 1:205) {
        newlist[[i]] <- lapply(seq(2,150), function(x) list1[[i]][1:x,])
 }
```

the code works though, However it takes up to much memory everytime it goes into the loop. Resulting in a terminate R session error while i run this.

Is there a better solution for this, which doesn't take that much memory?

Comment: why two loops? `newlist <- lapply(1:150, function(i) list1[[i]][1:i])`

Comment: You might want to switch to using the `data.table` package. It use handles memory better than `data.frame`.

Comment: Lots of the advice here applies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8474941/636656 .  Pick a strategy: either use lapply with column selection, or a for loop. And your lapply call would be better served passing the list than the vector.