# interpolation/lookup in R

Tags: r, gps, interpolation, lookup

I'm switching to R from excel and was wondering how to do this in R.
I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
df1<-data.frame(Zipcode=c("7941AH","7941AG","7941AH","7941AZ"),
                From=c(2,30,45,1),
                To=c(20,38,57,8),
                Type=c("even","mixed","odd","mixed"),
                GPS=c(12345,54321,11221,22331)) 

df2<-data.frame(zipcode=c("7914AH", "7914AH", "7914AH", "7914AG","7914AG","7914AZ"), 
                housenum=c(18, 19, 50, 32, 104,11))
```

First dataset contains zipcode, house number range (from and to), type meaning if the range contains even, odd or mixed house numbers and gps coordinates. Second dataset contains only address (zipcode, house number).

What I want to do is to lookup gps coordinates for df2. For example address with zipcode 7941AG and housenumber 18 (even number between 2 and 20) has gps coordinate 12345.

**Update:**
As it didn't cross my mind that the size of the dataset is important for the chosen solution (I know, bit naive...) here some extra information:
Actual size of df1 is 472.000 observations and df2 has 1.1 million observations. The number of unique zipcodes in df1 is 280.000. I stumbled upon this post [speed up the loop operation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r)
with some interesting findings, but I don't know how to incorporate this in the solution provided by @josilber

Comment: Do you mean to use `7941AH` in your example? Your `df1` doesn't cover 7941AG from 2 to 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given large data frames, your best bet may be to merge `df1` and `df2` by their zip codes (aka get every pair of rows from the data frames where they have the same zip code), filter by the house number criteria, remove duplicates (cases where multiple rules from `df1` match), and then store the information about all the matched houses. Let's start with a sample dataset of the size you indicated:

```
set.seed(144)
df1 <- data.frame(Zipcode=sample(1:280000, 472000, replace=TRUE),
                  From=sample(1:50, 472000, replace=TRUE),
                  To=sample(51:100, 472000, replace=TRUE),
                  Type=sample(c("even", "odd", "mixed"), 472000, replace=TRUE),
                  GPS=sample(1:100, 472000, replace=TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(zipcode=sample(1:280000, 1.1e6, replace=TRUE),
                  housenum=sample(1:100, 1.1e6, replace=TRUE))
```

Now we can perform the efficient computation of the GPS data:

```
get.gps <- function(df1, df2) {
  # Add ID to df2
  df2$id <- 1:nrow(df2)
  m <- merge(df1, df2, by.x="Zipcode", by.y="zipcode")
  m <- m[m$housenum >= m$From &
         m$housenum <= m$To &
         (m$Type == "mixed" |
          (m$Type == "odd" & m$housenum %% 2 == 1) |
          (m$Type == "even" & m$housenum %% 2 == 0)),]
  m <- m[!duplicated(m$id) & !duplicated(m$id, fromLast=TRUE),]
  GPS <- rep(NA, nrow(df2))
  GPS[m$id] <- m$GPS
  return(GPS)
}
system.time(get.gps(df1, df2))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  16.197   0.561  17.583
```

This is a much more acceptable runtime -- 18 seconds instead of the 90 hours that you estimated in the comment of my other answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would just loop through each of the elements in `df2`, implementing the logic needed to check if the zip code matches and the element ranges are right and the even/odd are correct:

```
# Clean up data (character zip codes and fix the 7914 vs. 7941 issue in zip codes)
df2<-data.frame(zipcode=c("7941AH", "7941AH", "7941AH", "7941AG","7941AG","7941AZ"), 
                housenum=c(18, 19, 50, 32, 104,11))
df1$Zipcode <- as.character(df1$Zipcode)
df2$zipcode <- as.character(df2$zipcode)

# Loop to compute the GPS values
sapply(seq(nrow(df2)), function(x) {
  m <- df2[x,]
  matched <- df1$Zipcode == m$zipcode &
    m$housenum >= df1$From &
    m$housenum <= df1$To &
    (df1$Type == "mixed" |
     (df1$Type == "odd" & m$housenum %% 2 == 1) |
     (df1$Type == "even" & m$housenum %% 2 == 0))
  if (sum(matched) != 1) {
    return(NA)  # No matches or multiple matches
  } else {
    return(df1$GPS[matched])
  }
})
# [1] 12345    NA    NA 54321    NA    NA
```

By inspection, only the first and fourth elements of `df2` are matched by one of the rules in `df1`.

Comment: This works fine! However my actual dataset contains about 1 million observations. I timed the execution for 500, 1000 and 1500 observations with proc.time() and if I extrapolate this it will take about 90 hours to complete. Any ideas why R has so much trouble with looping?

Comment: @nsnvc interesting -- your question hadn't mentioned anything about having a large dataset where efficiency was an issue. Could you update your question with details about your dataset (number of zip codes, size of `df1`, size of `df2`)?

Comment: I have updates the original question. Btw, I just saw that you are one of the developers of 15.071x: The Analytics Edge. What a great course!! It's the reason I switched to R.