# R: Speed up Code for Levenschtein match

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, levenshtein-distance

I have two data tables which contain city names. The first `mydf` contains a list of cities we want to check. It consists of 18990 records. The second is a reference table i have been given which contains 353766 rows.

The structure of both tables is below (head 10)

```
structure(list(country = "LT", city = "VILNIUS", cleaned_city = "VILNIUS"), .Names = c("country", 
"city", "cleaned_city"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Table myref can contain cities that don't exist in `mydf` as its our reference table. Table `mydf` can contain cities that don't exits in `myref` as we are trying to determine what is missing from our reference table.
Table `mydf` may contain cities that are spelt subtly different to what we have in `myref`.

The cities exist from many countries so using for loops I implemented the following logic:

1. loop through every country in `mydf`
2. loop through every city in `mydf` for the country in loop 1 and implement a levenschtein match between the same country in the reference table (different countries can have similiar towns so this is the reason for the first loop)
3. record the %match and the most similar town in the `mydf` table for manual examination after the code has run.

I have tried creating a second column in the mydf table with every possible match to a city within that country and then run the levenschtein match but i ran out of memory (the table is too large and im on 32 bit windows laptop) which is why i went back to the for loops which is taking days to run. Can anyone help. My code is below (i know for loops are probably the least optimal way to approach this so this should be a great learning experience) and if any more information is needed please let me know

```
# Initialize variables, my.country contains all the unique countries in     mydf
my.country <- unique(mydf$country)
mydf.sample <- mydf[0, ]
myref.sample <- myref[0, ]
mydf.final <- mydf[0, ] %>%
  mutate(levdist = 0,
      town.match = '')

# For each country, Take each item in mydf, compare it to every record     in the reference table myref
# get the best levenschtein match and score
# add the levenschtein score and the city matched to mydf

for(intcountry in 1:length(my.country))
  {

  # Filter the mydf Table & myRef Table to specific countries based on the intcountry iteration
  mydf.sample <- mydf %>% 
    filter(country == my.country[intcountry])

  myref.sample <- mydf %>% 
    filter(country == my.country[intcountry])

  # Inititalize the temp vector to the size of the mydf size
    vector <- character(length(mydf.sample))

# Set Up Levenschtein Distance
# For every Record in the Dataframe to be checked
for(item in 1:nrow(mydf.sample))
{
  # For every Record in the Reference Table
  for(k in 1:nrow(myref))
  {
    vector[k] = levenshteinSim(mydf.sample$City[item],myref$city[k])
  }
  # Get index of the highest levenschtein match
  max.match.index = match(max(vector),vector)
  mydf.sample$levdist[item] = max(vector)
  mydf.sample$town.match[item] = myref$city[max.match.index]
  vector <- character(length(mydf.sample))
}
mydf.final<- rbind(mydf.sample, mydf.final)
 }
```

Comment: You can try n-gram. Levenshtein is essential a suffix array/tree and is difficult.

Comment: Try reading through this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r) about speeding up your for loops. 

Also a few of your data.frames are not in your example. That makes it hard to check your code

Answer (score 1):

When speed and memory issues are important, then the `data.table` package is often a good alternative. As you didn't provide example data which illustrate the problem, I created some (see the end of this answer for the `dput`s of the used data).

**1:** First you have to transform your dataframes into datatables:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf, key=c("country","city"))
setDT(myref, key=c("country","city"))
```

With the `key=c("country","city")` part you also create a reference for each datatable.

**2:** Now you can easily remove the entries in `mydf` which are also in the reference datset `myref` with:

```
mydf <- mydf[!myref]
```

which gives:

```
> mydf
   country   city
1:      GB LONDON
2:      LT KAUNAS
3:      LT VILNUS
```

As you can see, the record (row) for "VILNIUS" is removed from `mydf` but the record/row for "VILNUS" is not because it is not an exact match.

*EDIT: I removed the 3rd and 4th option as they seem not to be working properly.*

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(country = c("LT","GB","LT","LT"), city = c("VILNIUS","LONDON","KAUNAS","VILNUS")), .Names = c("country", "city"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
myref <- structure(list(country = c("LT","NL"), city = c("VILNIUS","AMSTERDAM")), .Names = c("country", "city"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: Hi @Jaap, I tried to set the key using your example setDT(mydf, key=c("country","city")). I got the error Error in setDT(mydf, key = c("country", "city")) : unused argument (key = c("country", "city"))

Comment: @JohnSmith Strange. It works at my system. Which version of `data.table` are you using?

Comment: hi @Jaap it says data.table_1.9.4

Comment: @JohnSmith That's an older version of `data.table`. You will have to update to v1.9.6

Comment: Hi @Jaap, sorry for the delay, proxy settings in work in order to update. Is there anyway using your second method we can specify the similarity...so towns 80% similar? Similarly is it possible to see what they have been matched to in the reference table so analysts can confirm manually?

Comment: @JohnSmith See the edit for why I removed option 3 & 4. At this moment i'm stuck as well in finding a solution with `data.table`.