# R - Very slow loop on data frame to replace values

Tags: r

I think exemple are easier to understand.
So here is how to generate a small fake data set as an exemple :

```
library(tidyr)
day_event<- as.Date("2017-03-01") + 0:6
a<-rep(1,7)
b<-as.numeric(c("", rep(1,6)))
c<-as.numeric(c("","",rep(1,5)))
df_1<-data.frame(day_event,a,b,c)
names(df_1)[2]<-"2017-03-08"
names(df_1)[3]<-"2017-03-09"
names(df_1)[4]<-"2017-03-10"

> df_1
  day_event 2017-03-08 2017-03-09 2017-03-10
1  2017-03-01          1         NA         NA
2  2017-03-02          1          1         NA
3  2017-03-03          1          1          1
4  2017-03-04          1          1          1
5  2017-03-05          1          1          1
6  2017-03-06          1          1          1
7  2017-03-07          1          1          1
```

I get the data set in df2 format but using tidyr I can go from one format to the other :

```
df_2<-gather(df_1, day_measure, measure, -day_event)
> df_2
 day_event  day_measure measure
1   2017-03-01 2017-03-08       1
2   2017-03-02 2017-03-08       1
3   2017-03-03 2017-03-08       1
4   2017-03-04 2017-03-08       1
5   2017-03-05 2017-03-08       1
6   2017-03-06 2017-03-08       1
7   2017-03-07 2017-03-08       1
8   2017-03-01 2017-03-09      NA
9   2017-03-02 2017-03-09       1
10  2017-03-03 2017-03-09       1
11  2017-03-04 2017-03-09       1
12  2017-03-05 2017-03-09       1
13  2017-03-06 2017-03-09       1
14  2017-03-07 2017-03-09       1
15  2017-03-01 2017-03-10      NA
16  2017-03-02 2017-03-10      NA
17  2017-03-03 2017-03-10       1
18  2017-03-04 2017-03-10       1
19  2017-03-05 2017-03-10       1
20  2017-03-06 2017-03-10       1
21  2017-03-07 2017-03-10       1
```

For the context, it represents measures of an event that happened on day_event.
But depending on the day the measure is performed the measure of the event on event_day can be different !

My probleme is that I only measure events seven days back : that's why the measure on day_mesure = '2017-03-09' for the day_event = '2017-03-01' is NA

I would like to replace this NA by the last measured perform (7 days after the day_event) : in this case replace by the measure made on '2017-03-08'

I tried

```
for (i in 1:length(df_2$measure)){
    row<- df_2[i,]
    if (row$day_event +7 < row$day_measure & length(df_2[df_2$day_event == row$day_event & df_2$day_measure == row$day_event + 7,]$measure)>0){
      row$measure<-df_2[df_2$day_event == row$day_event & df_2$day_measure == row$day_event + 7,]$measure
      df_2[i,]<-row
    }
}
```

It worked :)
But on my real data set which is larger it takes forever :(

I think R doesn't like such loops ! Can you think of another method ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe the fill function also from the tidyr package will do the trick

Comment: It is known that indexing R data.frames is slow, and that for-loops are very slow in R, so the combination of the two would make for a slow process. It is better practice to use the `apply` family of functions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r

Comment: Would _last observation carried forward_ do it for you? For instance, `na.locf()` from the `zoo` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are functions available which are built for this particular purpose which is known as *last observation carried forward*. One of the functions is `na.locf()`from the `zoo` package:

With that, the complete issue becomes a one-liner (I'm using `data.table` here because I'm more fluent in and it's usually faster with larger data.tables):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_2)[order(day_event, day_measure), measure := zoo::na.locf(measure), by = day_event]
```

Here, the rows are ordered by event date and subsequently be measure date. Then, missing elements are filled by *last observation carried forward*. In addition, the whole operation is grouped by event date to make sure that no false values are being carried forward if the first measurement in each group already is `NA`.

This is even faster than the OP's own answer which can be demonstrated by a benchmark (using the `microbenchmark` package)

#### Benchmark results

```
#Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#    loop 20.867890 22.037188 23.052667 22.665122 23.510681 27.535109   100   c
#   apply  9.011630  9.498314  9.834324  9.752323  9.994688 12.862594   100  b 
# na.locf  1.971389  2.132780  2.211467  2.226080  2.290762  2.656973   100 a
```

#### Benchmark code

As all 3 methods change the data in place we need to keep a copy of the original data.

```
library(data.table)
df_0 <- copy(df_2)
library(tidyr)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  loop = {
    df_2 <- copy(df_0)
    for (i in 1:length(df_2$measure)){
      row <- df_2[i,]
      if (row$day_event +7 < row$day_measure & length(df_2[df_2$day_event == row$day_event & df_2$day_measure == row$day_event + 7,]$measure)>0){
        row$measure<-df_2[df_2$day_event == row$day_event & df_2$day_measure == row$day_event + 7,]$measure
        df_2[i,]<-row
      }
    }
  },
  apply = {
    df_2 <- copy(df_0)
    df_temp <- df_2 %>% 
      dplyr::filter(day_event < day_measure - 7)

    df_temp$measure <- apply(X = df_temp
                             , MARGIN = 1
                             , FUN = function(x) {
                               (df_2 %>% dplyr::filter(
                                 day_event == x[[1]] & day_measure == (as.Date(x[[1]], format = "%Y-%m-%d") + 7)
                               ))$measure

                             })

    df_2 <- rbind(df_2 %>% dplyr::filter(day_event >= day_measure - 7)
                  , df_temp
    )

  },
  na.locf = {
    df_2 <- copy(df_0)
    df_2[order(day_event, day_measure), measure := zoo::na.locf(measure), by = day_event]
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing what someone from my organization answered :
Yes the solution was to use `apply`
Here is how :

```
df_temp <- df_2 %>% 
  dplyr::filter(day_event < day_measure - 7)

df_temp$measure <- apply(X = df_temp
                         , MARGIN = 1
                         , FUN = function(x) {
                            (df_2 %>% dplyr::filter(
                              day_event == x[[1]] & day_measure == (as.Date(x[[1]], format = "%Y-%m-%d") + 7)
                              ))$measure

                    })

df_2 <- rbind(df_2 %>% dplyr::filter(day_event >= day_measure - 7)
              , df_temp
)
```

My sample was only 42k rows but the for loop takes several hours 
This solution takes about 30s

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another solution proposed by someone else in my organisation : 
This solution is based on `dplyr` and seems to be faster than the `apply` solution I gave last week

```
library(tidyr)
day_event<- as.Date("2017-03-01") + 0:6
a<-rep(1,7)
b<-as.numeric(c("", rep(1,6)))
c<-as.numeric(c("","",rep(1,5)))
df_1<-data.frame(day_event,a,b,c)
names(df_1)[2]<-"2017-03-08"
names(df_1)[3]<-"2017-03-09"
names(df_1)[4]<-"2017-03-10"

df_1

df_2<-gather(df_1, day_measure, measure, -day_event)



fill_measure <- function(day_event, day_measure, measure){
  # return a modified measure vector
  # day_event should have only a single value here

  # test if correct day_measure exist
  if (any(day_measure == day_event + 7)){
    rst <- measure
    rst[day_measure > day_event + 7] <- measure[day_measure == day_event + 7]
  }else{
    rst <- measure
  }

  return(rst)
}

test <- df_2 %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(day_event) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(measure_new = fill_measure(day_event, day_measure, measure)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Comment: Is it faster than `na.locf()`?

Comment: I couldn't see the difference.
Both solutions are really fast.
Thx