# R creating 5 variables with column name suffix 1 through 5 using loop

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create an iterative function in R using a loop or array, which will create three variables and three data frames with the same 1-3 suffix. My current code is:

```
function1 <- function(b1,lvl1,lvl2,lvl3,b2,x) {

 lo1 <- exp(b1*lvl1 + b2*x)
 lo2 <- exp(b1*lvl2 + b2*x)
 lo3 <- exp(b1*lvl3 + b2*x)

 out1 <- t(c(lv1,lo1))
 out2 <- t(c(lvl2,lo2))
 out3 <- t(c(lvl3,lo3))

 out <- rbind(out1, out2, out3)
 colnames(out) <- c("level","risk")
 return(out)
}

function1(.18, 1, 2, 3, .007, 24)
```

However, I would like to iterate the same line of code three times to create lo1, lo2, lo3, and out1, out2 and out3. The syntax below is completely wrong because I don't know how to use two arguments in a for-loop, or nest a for loop within a function, but as a rough idea:

```
function1 <- function(b1,b2,x) {

for (i in 1:3) {

loi <- exp(b1*i + b2*x)
return(lo[i])

outi <- t(c(i, loi)
return(out[i])

}

out <- rbind(out1, out2, out3)
colnames(out) <- c("level","risk")
return(out)
}

function1(.18,.007,24)
```

The output should look like:

```
level  risk
1      1.42
2      1.70
3      2.03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, the `for` loops are really **inefficient**. A good practice is to use all the functions from the `apply` family and try to use as much as possible `vectorization`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r) are some discussions about this.

For your work, you can simply do it with the `dataframe` structure. Here the example:

```
# The function
function1 <- function(b1,b2,level,x) {
  # Create the dataframe with the level column
  df = data.frame("level" = level)

  # Add the risk column
  df$risk = exp(b1*df$level + b2*x)

  return(df)
}

# Your variables
b1 = .18
b2 = .007
level = c(1,2,3)

# Your process
function1(b1, b2, level, 24)
#   level     risk
# 1     1 1.416232
# 2     2 1.695538
# 3     3 2.029927
```

Comment: Your answer is a lot better, but there is nothing inherently bad about a loop in R, or good about `apply`.

Comment: Ok, thanks that worked! I appreciate the alternative-I didn't know that about loops.