# Multiple for loop time computation very high in R

Tags: r

I have data about machines in the following form
Number of rows - 900k

**Data**

```
          A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
         ---- -- --- ---- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
     1    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0
     2    0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
     3    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

1 indicates that the machine was active and 0 indicates that it was inactive.

I want my output to look like

```
          A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
         ---- -- --- ---- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
     1    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
     2    0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
     3    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

Basically all I am trying to do is look for zeros in a particular row and if that zero is surrounded by ones on either side, replace 0 with 1

example -

in row 1 you have zero in column J
but you also have 1 in column I and K
which means I replace that 0 by 1 because it is surrounded by 1s

The code I am using is this

```
  for(j in 2:13) {
    if(data[i,j]==0 && data[i,j-1]==1 && data[i,j+1]==1){
      data[i,j] = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to reduce the time computation for this? This takes me almost 30 mins to run in R. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @d.b Ohh yeah! Thanks. Updating the post. Appreciate it man

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speed up the loop operation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r)

Comment: hmm i get around 2s to run your code for a 900,000 by 14 matrix

Comment: @H1 `set.seed(0L);
data <- matrix(sample(0:1, 900e3*14, TRUE), ncol=14);
for (i in 1:900e3) {
    for(j in 2:13) {
        if(data[i,j]==0 && data[i,j-1]==1 && data[i,j+1]==1) {
            data[i,j] = 1
        }
    }
}` on R-3.6.1 Win7 x64

Comment: @yifyan I saw that but the fact that I was using multiple for loops made me repost this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `gsub` to replace any instances of `101` with `111` using the following code:

```
collapsed <- gsub('101', '111', apply(df1, 1, paste, collapse = ''))
data <- as_tibble(t(matrix(unlist(sapply(collapsed, strsplit, split = '')), nrow = numLetters)))
names(data) <- LETTERS[1:numLetters]
```

---

Here's a comparison of everyone's solutions:

```
library(data.table)
library(rbenchmark)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
numLetters <- 13
df <- as_tibble(matrix(round(runif(numLetters * 100)), ncol = numLetters))
names(df) <- LETTERS[1:numLetters]
benchmark(
  'gsub' = {
    data <- df
    collapsed <- gsub('101', '111', apply(data, 1, paste, collapse = ''))
    data <- as_tibble(t(matrix(unlist(sapply(collapsed, strsplit, split = '')), nrow = numLetters)))
    names(data) <- LETTERS[1:numLetters]
  },
  'for_orig' = {
    data <- df
    for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
      for(j in 2:(ncol(data) - 1)) {
        if(data[i, j] == 0 && data[i, j - 1] == 1 && data[i, j + 1] == 1) {
          data[i, j] = 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  'for_norows' = {
    data <- df
    for(j in 2:(ncol(data) - 1)) {
      data[, j] = ifelse(data[, j - 1] * data[, j + 1] == 1, 1, data[, j])
    }
  },
  'vectorize' = {
    data <- df
    for(i in seq(ncol(data) - 2) + 1) {
      condition <- data[, i - 1] == data[, i + 1] & data[, i - 1] == 1 & data[, i] == 0
      data[which(condition), i] <- 1
    }
  },
  'index' = {
    data <- df
    idx <- apply(data, 1, function(x) c(0, diff(x)))
    data[which(idx == -1 & lead(idx == 1), arr.ind = TRUE)[, 2:1]] <- 1
  },
  replications = 100
)
```

The indexing solution (which has since been deleted) wins hands-down in terms of computational time for a 13-by-100 data frame.

```
        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
3 for_norows          100    1.19    7.438      1.19        0         NA
2   for_orig          100    9.29   58.063      9.27        0         NA
1       gsub          100    0.28    1.750      0.28        0         NA
5      index          100    0.16    1.000      0.16        0         NA
4  vectorize          100    0.87    5.438      0.87        0         NA
  sys.child
3        NA
2        NA
1        NA
5        NA
4        NA
```

Comment: It might be worth to benchmark this on larger datasets, since not all methods scale well.

Answer (score 3):

this is faster because it does not require to iterate through the rows.

```
for(j in 2:13) {
  data[,j] = ifelse(data[,j-1] * data[,j+1]==1,1,data[,j])
  }
```

or a littlebit more optimized, without using `ifelse`

```
for(j in 2:(ncol(data) - 1)) {
  data[data[, j - 1] * data[, j + 1] == 1, j] <- 1
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Cut the time by using vectorized operations. As you are planning to do the same thing for every row, this can be done by utilizing the vectorized conditional statements.

```
for(i in seq(ncol(data) - 2) + 1){ #<== all but last and first column 
    #Find all neighbouring columns that are equal, where the the center column is equal to 0 
    condition <- data[, i - 1] == data[, i + 1] & data[, i - 1] == 1 & data[, i] == 0
    #Overwrite only the values that holds the condition
    data[which(condition), i] <- 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid loops altogether and use indexing to replace all the values at once:

```
  nc <- ncol(df)
  df[, 2:(nc - 1)][df[, 1:(nc - 2)] * df[, 3:nc] == 1] <- 1
```