# Read.XLS multiple files in loop need to skip if sheet is missing

Tags: r

I am trying to batch read in Excel files into R, but I need R to skip and continue the loop if the sheet name in question is missing.

```
library(xlsx)    
file.list <- list.files(recursive=T,pattern='*.xlsx')  #get files list from folder
for(i in 1:length(file.list))
{
  filename=file.list[i]
  data=read.xlsx(file = filename, sheetName="Income Statement", startColumn=2, startRow=4, header = T)
  assign(x = filename,value = data)
}
```

I assume I need to add an if else statement within this but I am not sure. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using an `if()`:

```r
library(xlsx)

file.list <- list.files(pattern = '*.xlsx', recursive = TRUE)

for(i in 1:length(file.list)) {
  filename <- file.list[i]
  sheets <- getSheets(loadWorkbook(filename))
  if("Income Statement" %in% names(sheets)) {
    data <- read.xlsx(file = filename, 
                      sheetName = "Income Statement", 
                      startColumn = 2, 
                      startRow = 4, 
                      header = TRUE)
    assign(x = filename, value = data)
  }
}
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer provides a sufficient solution.

However, if the number of files that are required to read is larger, it might be worth to avoid for loops altogether and rewrite the solution using `lapply`.

Few additional tweaks could be added:

- You could use `data.table` `rbindlist` to bind each file into a single big `data.frame` / `data.table` (to avoid multiple data.frames in global environment). This assumes that all loaded data share the structure - this is more concise. This can be also achieved in `base` with `do.call(rbind, "yourlist")` but you will loose the "id" column.
- You can implement some sort of percentage counter to show how many files were loaded using `cat(round(i / length(test) * 100, 3), "%    \r")` which is also noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50528290/3223143).
- There's number of packages that can be used to do this task. I would **recommend** `openxlsx` and avoid the `xlsx`. The `openxlsx` removes the dependency on Java. There's also `readxl` which is worth mentioning. The solution below is using `openxlsx`

The following solution should achieve similar results but should be faster than a for loop. As no data example was provided, you will have to play with some of the arguments in `openxlsx::read.xlsx` to specify the range of the sheet you want to load.

```
test <- list.files(recursive = TRUE, pattern = "*.xlsx")

as.data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(lapply(1:length(test), function(i){
        cat(round(i / length(test) * 100, 3), "%    \r")
        tmp_name <- test[i]
        tmp_sheets <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(tmp_name)
        if ("Income Statement" %in% tmp_sheets) {
                tmp_data <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(
                        tmp_name, 
                        sheet = "Income Statement", 
                        startRow = 4)
                assign(x = tmp_name, value = tmp_data)
        }
        
}
), idcol = "id"))
```