# in or out of a for loop in R - calculating the diagonal product of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, for-loop

I'm trying to find the maximum diagonal product of 2 digit numbers in a 20x20 matrix.

This gives an error message :

```
i <- 17:1
z <- for (j in 1:(18-i))
        {b <- max ((x[i,j]*x[i+1,j+1]*x[i+2,j+2]*x[i+3,j+3]))}}
```

But this doesn't:

```
z <- for (i <- 17:1)
{for (j in 1:(18-i))
        {b <- max ((x[i,j]*x[i+1,j+1]*x[i+2,j+2]*x[i+3,j+3]))}}
```

but the second version gives me a number too small .  Why does the first one not work, i think it would yield the correct answer, but i don't understand the error message.

Comment: http://www.philender.com/courses/multivariate/notes/matr.html and max()

Comment: Actually, neither of your solutions work. I've edited your entry to better reflect your question. If you don't agree, just roll back.

Answer (score 6):

This looks wrong.

You cannot assign the result of a `for` loop to a variable. And `max()` is over a scalar variable which is nonsense.  Lastly, matrix `x` isn't specified.  I'd retry with something smaller, and maybe even print some interim results to screen.

*Walk before you run* is still good advice.  Later you can still vectorise for a sprint solution.

Comment: wouldn't b be a vector from which max would give the maximum value?

Comment: Also, to get the data, i used read.table("filename") so i'm not exactly sure if it's in matrix form or whatever a table is.

Comment: ok, it's a data frame -- is it harder to work with data frames or matrices?

Comment: I think you mean you __can't__ assign the result of a for loop to a variable (in recent versions of R, anyway)

Comment: Thanks, Hadley. One day I will learn to proof-read. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, contrary to Dirk I believe that you should be aware of vectorization in R as soon as possible. The loop structure you try to implement is far from optimal, and actually redundant. Using a for-loop should be done only in very specific cases. Check the discusison in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar). Take a look at the help files of convenience functions like `diag()`, `combn()`, `prod()` and `apply()`.

It's easy to combine them to do what you want :

```
x <-matrix(1:400,ncol=20)

Diag <- diag(x)

Id <- combn(1:length(Diag),2)

Diag.prod <- apply(matrix(Diag[Id],ncol=2),1,prod)

Max.Diag.prod <- max(Diag.prod)
```

Edit : You use a data frame, but you can use `as.matrix(x)` to convert this easily to a matrix.