# Combining conditions

Tags: r

my recode attempts

```
df$test[(df$1st==(1:3) & df$2nd <= 4)] <- 1
df$test[(df$1st==(1:3) & df$2nd <= 5)] <- 2
df$test[(df$1st==(1:3) & df$2nd <= 6)] <- 3
```

result in a `"longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"` warning and a lot of `NA`s in `df$test`, even though some recodes work correctly.
What am I missing? Any help appreciated.

dw

Answer (score 5):

Problem is in this line:

```
df$1st==(1:3)
```

You could use `%in%`

```
df$1st %in% (1:3)
```

Warning comes cause you compare vectors of different lengths (`1:3` has length 3 and `df$1st` has length "only you know what").

Beside I think you missed that your values are overwritten: `df$2nd <= 4` is also `df$2nd <= 6` so all 1 and 2 are overwrite by 3.

Comment: sorry, overwriting only takes place in my example, which I put down too fast and erronous...

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what you're trying to achieve with `df$1st==(1:3)`, but it probably doesn't do what you think it does. It [*recycles*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Vector-arithmetic) `c(1,2,3)` as many times as it needs to make it as long as `df`.

If you are trying to check if `df$1st` is between 1 and 3, you might want to spell it out:

```
df$1st>=1 & df$1st<=3
```

Comment: Thanks alot, aix! The problem was indeed the 1:3; spelling it out worked.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider using  `transform()` to deal with recoding issues such as this. `transform()` will perform slower than the logical indexing method, but is easier to digest the intent of the code. A good discussion of the pros and cons of the different methods can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406873/coding-practice-in-r-what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-different-sty). Consider:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame("first" = sample(1:5, 10e5, TRUE), "second" = sample(4:8, 10e5, TRUE))

df <- transform(df
    , test =      ifelse(first %in% 1:3 & second == 4, 1
            , ifelse(first %in% 1:3 & second == 5, 2
            , ifelse(first %in% 1:3 & second == 6, 3, NA)))
    )
```

Secondly, the column names `1st` and `2nd` are not syntactically valid column names. Take a look at `make.names()` for more details on what constitutes valid column names. When working with a `data.frame`, you can use/abuse the `check.names` argument. For example:

```
> df <- data.frame("1st" = sample(1:5, 10e5, TRUE), "2nd" = sample(4:8, 10e5, TRUE), check.names = FALSE)
> colnames(df)
[1] "1st" "2nd"
> df <- data.frame("1st" = sample(1:5, 10e5, TRUE), "2nd" = sample(4:8, 10e5, TRUE), check.names = TRUE)
> colnames(df)
[1] "X1st" "X2nd"
```