# Make Emacs ESS follow R style guide

Tags: r, emacs, coding-style, elisp, ess

I've been using Emacs/ESS for quite a while, and I'm familiar with [Hadley's R style recommendations](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Style). I'd like to follow these conventions in ESS, like those nice spaces around operators, space after comma and after `if` statement, before curly braces, etc.

Did anyone even bothered to follow this style guide at all? IMHO, official style recommendations are quite modest, and they say nothing about the style whatsoever. [Google R style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html) are too similar with the ones I use when I code in JavaScript, so it's a no-no.

Long story short: ***is there anyone with (e)LISP skills willing to implement (Hadley's) style guide for ESS?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The good point of Hadley's guide is spaceing around operators (except maybe around /)

There is a [smart-operator](http://xwl.appspot.com/ref/smart-operator.el) package which implements it for almost every operator.

This is my setup (uncoment operators which you want to use):

```
(setq smart-operator-mode-map
  (let ((keymap (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key keymap "=" 'smart-operator-self-insert-command)
    ;; (define-key keymap "<" 'smart-operator-<)
    ;; (define-key keymap ">" 'smart-operator->)
    ;; (define-key keymap "%" 'smart-operator-%)
    (define-key keymap "+" 'smart-operator-+)
    ;; (define-key keymap "-" 'smart-operator--)
    ;; (define-key keymap "*" 'smart-operator-*)
    ;; (define-key keymap "/" 'smart-operator-self-insert-command)
    (define-key keymap "&" 'smart-operator-&)
    (define-key keymap "|" 'smart-operator-self-insert-command)
    ;; (define-key keymap "!" 'smart-operator-self-insert-command)
    ;; (define-key keymap ":" 'smart-operator-:)
    ;; (define-key keymap "?" 'smart-operator-?)
    (define-key keymap "," 'smart-operator-,)
    ;; (define-key keymap "." 'smart-operator-.)
    keymap)
  "Keymap used my `smart-operator-mode'.")
```

See also a nice discussion on R styles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406873/coding-practice-in-r-what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-different-st/4421103).

[edit] I am also using the defacto camelCase style of R code for globals. The underscore-separated names for local variables - it's easy to differentiate.

There is a special `subword` mode in emacs which redefines all editing and navigation commands to be used on capitalized sub-words

```
(global-subword-mode)
```

Comment: Perfect! And it also answers another rant of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803317/emacs-mode-function-that-wraps-operators-with-spaces

Comment: See also [electric-operator](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/electric-operator) which is similar to smart-operator but has native support for R.

Answer (score 29):

I don't write Elisp, and I disagree with Hadley about the stylistic merits of underscores. Moreover, Hadley is still lost in the desert of not using the [OneTrueEditor](http://xkcd.com/378/) so we can expect no help from him on this on this issue.

But if you are open to follow R Core rather than Hadley, below is what the [R Internals manual, section 8. "R Coding Standards"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#R-coding-standards) recommends.  To me, it is R Core who defines R style first and foremost.  Google's and Hadley's styles are nice *secondary* recommendations.

Anyway, back to Elisp.  The following has served we well for many years, and I do like the fact that the basic R behaviour is similar to the Emacs C++ style as I happen to look at code in both modes a lot.

> [...]
>
> It is also important that code is written in a way that allows
>   others to understand it.  This is particularly helpful for fixing
>   problems, and includes using self-descriptive variable names,
>   commenting the code, and also formatting it properly.  The R Core Team
>   recommends to use a basic indentation of 4 for R and C (and most
>   likely also Perl) code, and 2 for documentation in Rd format.  Emacs
>   (21 or later) users can implement this indentation style by putting
>   the following in one of their startup files, and using customization
>   to set the `c-default-style' to`"bsd"' and `c-basic-offset' to`4'.)
>
> ```
>  ;;; ESS
>  (add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
>            (lambda ()
>              (ess-set-style 'C++ 'quiet)
>              ;; Because
>              ;;                                 DEF GNU BSD K&R  C++
>              ;; ess-indent-level                  2   2   8   5  4
>              ;; ess-continued-statement-offset    2   2   8   5  4
>              ;; ess-brace-offset                  0   0  -8  -5 -4
>              ;; ess-arg-function-offset           2   4   0   0  0
>              ;; ess-expression-offset             4   2   8   5  4
>              ;; ess-else-offset                   0   0   0   0  0
>              ;; ess-close-brace-offset            0   0   0   0  0
>              (add-hook 'local-write-file-hooks
>                        (lambda ()
>                          (ess-nuke-trailing-whitespace)))))
>  (setq ess-nuke-trailing-whitespace-p 'ask)
>  ;; or even
>  ;; (setq ess-nuke-trailing-whitespace-p t)
>  ;;; Perl
>  (add-hook 'perl-mode-hook
>            (lambda () (setq perl-indent-level 4)))
> ```
>
> (The `GNU' styles for Emacs' C and R modes use a basic indentation of
>   2, which has been determined not to display the structure clearly
>   enough when using narrow fonts.)

I think the only additions I regularly make are to follow the last commented-out snippet:

```
;; or even
(setq ess-nuke-trailing-whitespace-p t)
```

You can of course turn off the underscore toggle if you really need to code with underscores.

Comment: +1 I'm lost in the same desert as Hadley, but I'll give you +1 for linking to XKCD.

Comment: ==:-)  I knew someone would get a kick out of it.  Editor wars and style issues are way to personal anyway to be taken all *that* seriously.  That said, time you switch to Emacs, son!  ;-)

Comment: I sense some bad interpersonal vibes 'round here... =(
I won't discuss that one, though... I still admire both Hadley's and your work (I don't speak C/C++, so no Rcpp for me, but I tend to use littler more than Rscript). After all, I started using Emacs/ESS on your recommendation. I honestly believe that it's possible to get a useful mash-up of code from various sources. And I'd really want to see your `.emacs` tweaks related to R. =)

Comment: Ahh, it's all just friendly jestering.  I love Hadley almost as much as the next guy, but the underscores still keep me awake at night.  Not to mention the pastel colours in ggplot. Ouch.

Comment: That said, I'd be all for *someone* writing an ESS setup for his style, and/or for Google's. The more the merrier. Until then, I am rather content with what R Core has provided.

Comment: My brain isn't big enough to hold all those keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: You really only need a dozen or os, and if you select the commands by mouse, Emacs reminds you of the keyboard shortcuts. It is pretty easy to glide into this.

Comment: FWIW, I'm an anti-fan of pastel colours in `ggplot2`. But girls seem to love them, and since there's a plenty of estrogen swarming around in department of psychology, I have no worries when choosing the colour theme - the default one works just fine. Though the underscore solution is a bit uptight in ESS. But, to hell with it... it's a convention, you don't ask question, you just obey them. =/

Comment: @Andrie, it may seem overwhelming at first, but you'll get used to this after a while... Dammit, you'll even start adding your own!!! =)

Comment: There is a toggle too.  AFAICT it really is an old shortcut from when folks used to press a single _ to get ESS to insert <- for them.

Comment: OK, @DirkEddelbuettel, but, don't you sometimes want those pretty spaces around operators, spaces after commas... I mean, c'mon... =)

Comment: Yes, I much prefer "if (foo) {"  to "if(foo){" but I guess I must still be doing that by hand...

Comment: But why?!? O_o Save your keystrokes, joint arthritis is lurking around the corner! =)

Comment: @Dirk: just for you, I need to photoshop it so the vim guy is hitting him with an underscore. ;-)

Comment: Same with the timeless one involving the horse... of which this is reminding me a tad now ;-)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Here's a new one for you.  http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20080202231409/uncyclopedia/images/1/11/Beating-a-dead-horse.gif

Comment: Wow that guy is on a mission. I like his classic outfit though.

Answer (score 23):

With the development version of ESS (to be released in September 2015), just add to your `ess-mode-hook`:

```
(ess-set-style 'RStudio)
```

RStudio also has a 'Vertically align arguments' checkbox that is set by default. If you want to reproduce the behaviour when this setting is unchecked (as in Hadley's code), you'll need to change `ess-offset-arguments` to `prev-line`:

```
(setq ess-offset-arguments 'prev-line)
```

Please file an issue on https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS if you find an important discrepancy between ESS and RStudio indentation.

Answer (score 4):

Having the same style preference of the OP, I jumped here and I thank @lionel for your valid suggestions, but I had an issue coming from setting RStudio style in `~/emacs.d/init.el` with:

```
(ess-set-style 'RStudio)
```

Emacs/ESS refused to apply the style (4-space indent instead of the 2-space, not discussing style here :) ).

My advice for the novice, using the following hook in your `~/emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-r-style-hook)
(defun my-r-style-hook ()
  (when (string-match (file-name-extension buffer-file-name) "[r|R]$")
    (ess-set-style 'RStudio)))
```

will do the trick.

Comment: back to lionel's answer, it worked well with me. Did you check the `ess-style` variable? just type `M-: ess-style` and you should get the Rstudio style.

Comment: Disregard my answer! I was not setting the `ess-mode-hook` correctly. My solution just adds a hook for opening all the files ending with `[r|R]`

Answer (score 1):

One more component of the style guide which hasn't been covered here so far
is indentation when a function runs over multiple lines. The style guide
says to use indentation like

```
long_function_name <- function(a = "a long argument", 
                               b = "another argument",   # X
                               c = "another long argument") {
  # As usual code is indented by two spaces.
}
```

but using any of the default styles seems to indent line `X` by some fixed
number of spaces rather than up to the `(`. The solution is to [set
`ess-arg-function-offset` to some non-number](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/master/lisp/ess-mode.el#L411), e.g.

```
(set 'ess-arg-function-offset t)
```

This should be placed in a mode hook similar to @Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer. Also it must go *after* any calls to `ess-set-style` or it will be overridden.