# Emacs mode/function that wraps operators with spaces

Tags: emacs, coding-style

I remember that there was a mode for Emacs, or was it an option, can't recall, that prettified the code by placing space after operators like `,`, `.`, wrapped `=` with spaces, and some other cools stuff that I can't remember.

I reckon that this is pretty much language-specific issue, but I usually put space after commas, and wrap `=` with spaces. Any ideas about this mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [smart-operator.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartOperator).

Comment: Nah, it's wasn't that plugin, but it's definitely useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about [`smartchr.el`](https://github.com/imakado/emacs-smartchr/blob/master/smartchr.el)?
This is probably not what you are trying to recall, but I'm sure it works nicely for that purpose.

For example:

```
(require 'smartchr)
(global-set-key (kbd "=") (smartchr '(" = " " == " "=")))
```

With this configuration, when you type <kbd>=</kbd> several times,  `=`  is inserted and it rotates to  `==`  to `=` then back to  `=` .

Here is an introduction by the author (written in Japanese, but with a demo video and example of configuration): http://tech.kayac.com/archive/emacs-tips-smartchr.html