# Iterate over key/value pair from a list()

Tags: r

I'd like to know how I can iterate over a key/value pair from a list object in R, like the example below:

```
toto <- list(a="my name is",b="I'm called",c="name:")
myfun <- function(key,value) paste(value,key)
for( key in names(toto) ) toto[key] <- myfun(key,toto[[key]])
```

Is there a way to avoid the for loop (using lapply() or such). Would it be faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Just keep in mind that `lapply` still involves iteration, and while it is likely a little faster than `for`, this isn't always the case (and it certainly isn't equivalent to vectorizing the function). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar/2276001#2276001

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best solution of all is to simply call `paste` directly without a loop (it's vectorized already):

```
> paste(toto, names(toto))
[1] "my name is a" "I'm called b" "name: c"
```

A similar question [previously asked on R-Help](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg76150.html), with several creative solutions.  `lapply` cannot show the names within the function.  This function was provided by Romain Francois based on something by Thomas Lumley:

```
yapply <- function(X,FUN, ...) { 
  index <- seq(length.out=length(X)) 
  namesX <- names(X) 
  if(is.null(namesX)) 
    namesX <- rep(NA,length(X))

  FUN <- match.fun(FUN) 
  fnames <- names(formals(FUN)) 
  if( ! "INDEX" %in% fnames ){ 
    formals(FUN) <- append( formals(FUN), alist(INDEX=) )   
  } 
  if( ! "NAMES" %in% fnames ){ 
    formals(FUN) <- append( formals(FUN), alist(NAMES=) )   
  } 
  mapply(FUN,X,INDEX=index, NAMES=namesX,MoreArgs=list(...)) 
}
```

Here's an example of usage:

```
> yapply(toto, function( x ) paste(x, NAMES) )
             a              b              c 
"my name is a" "I'm called b"      "name: c"
```

Comment: And basic use of `mapply` to OP case will be `mapply(myfun, key=names(toto), value=toto)`.

Comment: @Marek Good point! I did think it worth covering more than just paste in case the OP had other usages in mind with the question.  I would also note that this is essentially what `yapply` does behind the scenes (see the last line of that function).

Comment: i would prefer `mapply` any day to `yapply` so that any decent R programmer can easily understand what you are doing since it is a "standard" apply function anyway.

Answer (score 24):

The R folks often don't like to give a straight answer to a simple question.

This is how you can iterate over key/value pairs in a list:

```
for (name in names(myList)) {
  print(name)
  print(myList[[name]])
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 5):

This should do it for you:

```
do.call(paste, list(toto, names(toto) ))
```

Comment: no need for do.call here. paste(toto,names(toto)) works just as fine. And is in my eyes even more elegant.