# Speed comparison of sapply with a composite function

Tags: r, performance, runtime

```
> system.time(sapply(rnorm(1000000,0,1), function (x) round(x,2)))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.78    0.11    2.89 
> system.time(round(rnorm(1000000,0,1),2))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.29    0.00    0.30
```

I was trying this out after reading the answers to the R tips question.  I did not expect sapply to be order of magnitude slower than the equivalent composite function in the above case.  Does anyone know why this is the case?  If i understand correctly sapply will vectorize and be near optimally fast.

Comment: Kohske is right. sapply merely creates an illusion or a poor substitute for real vectorization.  When you can, you should try to build all of your transformations with inherently vectorized functions.

Comment: The main purpose of `sapply` is to make loops easier to read (and save typing), not to speed things up.

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing here to sapply to - you only give it a single vector - not a list of vectors, and sapply converts the result to a (single column) matrix.

sapply is simplifying the result for you, but in doing so has to generate an array.

Compare if you give it a list:

```
system.time(sapply(list(rnorm(1000000,0,1)), function (x) round(x,2))) 
user  system elapsed 
 0.22    0.00    0.22 

system.time(sapply(rnorm(1000000,0,1), function (x) round(x,2))) 
user  system elapsed 
4.21    0.00    4.21
```

Comment: `sapply` calls `lapply` which operates element-wise on vectors.

Comment: thanks Hadley, I wasn't sure exactly what happens here - clearly it's the s(apply)implification here that takes the extra time though?

Comment: Hi, the first (list) case is like: for(i=1)round(x[[i]]), where x is list(rnorm(100000)). it is very similar to calling round(rnorm(100000)). the second case is like: for(i=1:100000)round(x[i]), where x is rnorm(100000). the extra time is not due to the simplification, but the loop.

Comment: Thanks to all the commenters and answers as I clearly did not understand sapply and will have to look into vectorization more deeply.

Answer (score 5):

probably sapply, which is a simple wrapper of lapply, is not vectorized. try this code:

```
system.time(sapply(rnorm(10), function (x) {print(length(x)); round(x,2)}))
```

and see the implementation here: https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/apply.c