# How to calculate for each element in a vector the fraction of elements in another vector that is smaller?

Tags: optimization, r, loops, performance

```
n<-100000   
aa<-rnorm(n)
bb<-rnorm(n)
system.time(lapply(aa, function(z){mean(bb<pnorm(z))}))
```

It takes too long to run this small code. Simply put, I have two vectors `aa` and `bb`. For each element of `aa`, say `aa[i]`, I want the proportion of `bb < aa[i]`

I found this article and tried to use it to speed up. But it does not work.
[Speed comparison of sapply with a composite function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600243/speed-comparison-of-sapply-with-a-composite-function)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Just a minor comment: Why not create `pnorm(z)` outside the function? That is, `aa <- pnorm(rnorm(n))`.

Comment: @Bernd Or `lapply(pnorm(aa), function(z){mean(bb<z)})`

Answer (score 7):

You may be able to use the `findInterval` function:

```
n <- 25000
aa <- rnorm(n)
bb <- rnorm(n)
system.time(q1 <- lapply(aa, function(z){mean(bb<pnorm(z))}))
#   user  system elapsed
# 20.057   2.544  22.807
system.time(q2 <- findInterval(pnorm(aa), sort(bb))/n)
#   user  system elapsed
#  0.020   0.000   0.021
all.equal(as.vector(q1, "numeric"), q2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Note that `findInterval` returns indices, so I've divided the result by `n`. If you can sort `pnorm(aa)` before giving it to `findInterval`, it will be even faster.

Comment: Fantastic! I had never encountered the findInterval function before.

Comment: @Ian What reminds me about http://unknownr.r-forge.r-project.org/. From author description: "Do you know how many functions there are in base R? How many of them do you know you don't know? Run `unk()` to discover your unknown unknowns. It's fast and it's fun!"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not meaning to be facetious but these are the types of problems that R is designed to solve without having to do every single calculation - ie, use statistics!

Assuming that the distributions are normal...

```
aa.new <- sample(aa, 1000)
bb.new <- sample(bb, 1000)

x <- lapply(aa.new, function(z){mean(bb.new<pnorm(z))})
x <- unlist(x)

mean(x)
```

You can be 99% certain that the proportion of bb < aa[i] falls between +/- 4% of mean(x).

For simple random sampling, 99% margin of error = 1.29/sqrt(n)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the proportion ' < aa[i]' then you should just determine the number of bb less than than each value of aa and then divide by length:

```
bbs <- sort(bb)
zz <- findInterval(aa, bbs)
zz <- zz/length(aa)
```

It does what you say you want, while your code I fear does not.