# Avoid two for loops in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a R code that can do convolution of two functions...

```
convolveSlow <- function(x, y) {  
nx <- length(x); ny <- length(y)  
xy <- numeric(nx + ny - 1)  
for(i in seq(length = nx)) {  
 xi <- x[[i]]  
        for(j in seq(length = ny)) {  
            ij <- i+j-1  
            xy[[ij]] <- xy[[ij]] + xi * y[[j]]  
        }  
    }  
    xy  
}
```

Is there a way to remove the two for loops and make the code run faster?

Thank you
San

Comment: It seems you are using lists of single element vectors rather than vectors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since R is very fast at computing vector operations, the most important thing to keep in mind when programming for performance is to vectorise as many of your operations as possible.

This means thinking hard about replacing loops with vector operations.  Here is my solution for fast convolution (50 times faster with input vectors of length 1000 each):

```
convolveFast <- function(x, y) {
    nx <- length(x)
    ny <- length(y)
    xy <- nx + ny - 1
    xy <- rep(0, xy)
    for(i in (1:nx)){
        j <- 1:ny
        ij <- i + j - 1
        xy[i+(1:ny)-1] <- xy[ij] + x[i] * y
    }
    xy
}
```

You will notice that the inner loop (for j in ...) has disappeared.  Instead, I replaced it with a vector operation.  j is now defined as a vector (j <- 1:ny).  Notice also that I refer to the entire vector y, rather than subsetting it (i.e. y instead of y[j]).

```
j <- 1:ny
ij <- i + j - 1
xy[i+(1:ny)-1] <- xy[ij] + x[i] * y
```

I wrote a small function to measure peformance:

```
measure.time <- function(fun1, fun2, ...){
    ptm <- proc.time()
    x1 <- fun1(...)
    time1 <- proc.time() - ptm

    ptm <- proc.time()
    x2 <- fun2(...)
    time2 <- proc.time() - ptm

    ident <- all(x1==x2)

    cat("Function 1\n")
    cat(time1)
    cat("\n\nFunction 2\n")
    cat(time2)
    if(ident) cat("\n\nFunctions return identical results")

}
```

For two vectors of length 1000 each, I get a 98% performance improvement:

```
x <- runif(1000)
y <- runif(1000)
measure.time(convolveSlow, convolveFast, x, y)

Function 1
7.07 0 7.59 NA NA

Function 2
0.14 0 0.16 NA NA

Functions return identical results
```

Comment: +1 nice solution. If you want to time your functions, you don't have to mess with `proc.time`, you could easily use `?system.time`

Comment: Move your definition of j before the loop for a further speedup.

Answer (score 10):

1. For vectors, you index with `[]`, not `[[]]`, so use `xy[ij]` etc
2. Convolution doesn't vectorise easily but one common trick is to switch to compiled code. The *Writing R Extensions* manual uses convolution as a running example and shows several alternative; we also use it a lot in the [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As Dirk says, compiled code can be a lot faster.  I had to do this for one of my projects and was surprised at the speedup: ~40x faster than Andrie's solution.

```
> a <- runif(10000)
> b <- runif(10000)
> system.time(convolveFast(a, b))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.814   0.001   7.818 
> system.time(convolveC(a, b))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.188   0.000   0.188
```

I made several attempts to speed this up in R before I decided that using C code couldn't be that bad (note: it really wasn't).  All of mine were slower than Andrie's, and were variants on adding up the cross-product appropriately.  A rudimentary version can be done in just three lines.

```
convolveNotAsSlow <- function(x, y) {
  xyt <- x %*% t(y)
  ds <- row(xyt)+col(xyt)-1
  tapply(xyt, ds, sum)
}
```

This version only helps a little.

```
> a <- runif(1000)
> b <- runif(1000)
> system.time(convolveSlow(a, b))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.167   0.000   6.170 
> system.time(convolveNotAsSlow(a, b))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.800   0.018   5.820
```

My best version was this:

```
convolveFaster <- function(x,y) {
  foo <- if (length(x)<length(y)) {y %*% t(x)} else { x %*% t(y) }
  foo.d <- dim(foo)
  bar <- matrix(0, sum(foo.d)-1, foo.d[2])
  bar.rc <- row(bar)-col(bar)
  bar[bar.rc>=0 & bar.rc<foo.d[1]]<-foo
  rowSums(bar)
}
```

This was quite a bit better, but still not nearly as fast as Andrie's

```
> system.time(convolveFaster(a, b))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.280   0.038   0.319
```

Answer (score 2):

The convolveFast function can be optimized a little by carefully using integer math only and replacing (1:ny)-1L with seq.int(0L, ny-1L):

```
convolveFaster <- function(x, y) {
    nx <- length(x)
    ny <- length(y)
    xy <- nx + ny - 1L
    xy <- rep(0L, xy)
    for(i in seq_len(nx)){
        j <- seq_len(ny)
        ij <- i + j - 1L
        xy[i+seq.int(0L, ny-1L)] <- xy[ij] + x[i] * y
    }
    xy
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `convolve(x, rev(y), type = "open")` in `stats`?

```
> x <- runif(1000)
> y <- runif(1000)
> system.time(a <- convolve(x, rev(y), type = "o"))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.032   0.000   0.032 
> system.time(b <- convolveSlow(x, y))
   user  system elapsed 
 11.417   0.060  11.443 
> identical(a,b)
[1] FALSE
> all.equal(a,b)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Yes, this is faster but isn't exact.  For example, it can give negative values when the exact value is close to zero.

Answer (score -1):

Some say the apply() and sapply() functions are faster than for() loops in R. You could convert the convolution to a function and call it from within apply().
However, there is evidence to the contrary
http://yusung.blogspot.com/2008/04/speed-issue-in-r-computing-apply-vs.html

Comment: I like the way I can pass apply function(s) to snowfall (using e.g. `sfApply`, `sfLapply`...) and do the calculations in parallel with minimal brainhurt.

Comment: only lapply can be really faster than a for-loop in some cases, and tapply over a combination of 2 factor is obviously a lot faster than a nested loop. But in general, the difference between the apply family and a for loop is about the side effects, not the speed. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar