# How to combine data from different columns, e.g. mean of surrounding columns for a given column

Tags: r, matrix, smoothing

I am trying to smooth a matrix by attributing the mean value of a window  covering *n* columns around a given column. I've managed to do it but I'd like to see how would be 'the R way' of doing it as I am making use of for loops. Is there a way to get this using `apply` or some function of the same family?

Example:

```
# create a toy matrix
mat <- matrix(ncol=200);
for(i in 1:100){ mat <- rbind(mat,sample(1:200, 200) )}
# quick visualization
image(t(mat))
```

[image]

This is the matrix before smoothing:

I wrote the function `smooth_mat` that takes a matrix and the length of the smoothing kernel:

```
smooth_row_mat <- function(k, k.d=5){
    k.range <- (k.d + 2):(ncol(k) - k.d - 1)
    k.smooth <- matrix(nrow=nrow(k))
    for( i in k.range){
            if (i  %% 10 == 0)      cat('\r',round(i/length(k.range), 2))
            k.smooth <- cbind( k.smooth, rowMeans(k[,c(  (i-1-k.d):(i-1) ,i, (i+1):(i + 1 - k.d) )]) )
    }
    return(k.smooth)
```

}

Now we use `smooth_row_mat()` with `mat`

```
mat.smooth <- smooth_mat(mat)
```

And we have successfully smoothed, on a row basis, the content of the matrix.

This is the matrix after:
[image]

This method is good for such a small matrix although my real matrices are around 40,000 x 400, still works but I'd like to improve my R skills.

Thanks!

Comment: `apply` is just a "pretty" `for` loop fyi

Comment: Really? I thought there were some important differences in terms of performance.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533246/why-is-apply-method-slower-than-a-for-loop-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a filter (running mean) across each row of your matrix as follows:

```
apply(k, 1, filter, rep(1/k.d, k.d))
```

Comment: Why would this work? It is just applying the same filter to the whole row and not based on the actual content of the row. Am I not getting something?

Comment: I understand now what filter is doing. I made the mistake of applying it to time series of the same number repeated many times, therefore the lack of differences.

Comment: It's a filter in the time-series sense of the word - `apply` will take the contents of the row, and effectively call `filter(contentsOfRow, rep(1/k.d, k.d))`  and `filter` takes every window of contentsOfRow (of same length as it's second argument), and produces a weighted sum of the elements in that window - I've given it equal weights, so it will be a windowed mean.

Comment: I understand now how `filter` is working although it gives weird results if used with apply. In detail, it is transposing the matrix. The filtered row gets transformed into column. Why does this happen?

Comment: From the help page: If each call to 'FUN' returns a vector of length 'n', then 'apply' returns an array of dimension 'c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])'   - so just wrap it in a `t()` if you want an apply-based result - or wrap the `filter` in a loop if you'd rather stick with a loop-based method.

Comment: Ahh I was lost reading about `filter` and not `apply`. Thanks my friend.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it, with the `raster` package.

First, create a matrix filled with random data and coerce it to a `raster` object.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(sample(200, 200*200, replace=TRUE), nc=200))
plot(r)
```

[image]

Then use the `focal` function to calculate a neighbourhood mean for a neighbourhood of `n` cells either side of the focal cell. The values in the matrix of weights you provide to the `focal` function determine how much the value of each cell contributes to the focal summary. For a mean, we say we want each cell to contribute `1/n`, so we fill a matrix of `n` columns, with values `1/n`. Note that `n` must be an odd number, and the cell in the centre of the matrix is considered the focal cell.

```
n <- 3
smooth_r <- focal(r, matrix(1/n, nc=n))
plot(smooth_r)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I chose the other answer as correct as it doesn't make use of external libraries.