# Loop compute inside cell R

Tags: r, loops, parsing, eval

I have this data.frame for example:

```
ds = data.frame(A= c("a","b","c","d") ,B= as.factor( c("4*10^4","2*10^3", "5000", "8*10^7")) )
```

I want to convert the column B to numeric and compute values inside it.

This code work for 1 cell:

```
eval(parse(text = "4*10^4"))
```

But when I try to loop over all my column with this line:

```
ds$B = for (i in ds$B) {eval(parse(text=i))}
```

It delete my column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In R, evaluate expressions within vector of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975229/in-r-evaluate-expressions-within-vector-of-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sapply`

```
ds$B <- sapply(as.character(ds$B), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
str(ds)
#'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ A: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 2 3 4
#$ B: num  4e+04 2e+03 5e+03 8e+07
```

Or if we are using the `for` loop, loop through the sequence of 'B' after converting to `character` class.

```
ds$B <- as.character(ds$B)
for(i in seq_along(ds$B)) ds$B[i] <- eval(parse(text=ds$B[i]))
ds$B <- as.numeric(ds$B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("c(", paste(ds$B, collapse = ","), ")")))
# [1] 4e+04 2e+03 5e+03 8e+07
```

What it does is convert your vector of strings `ds$B` to the string 
`"c(40000, 2000, 5000, 8e+07)"` and then parses it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)