# How to convert to numeric a sequence saved as a string?

Tags: r, string, numeric

How to convert to numeric a sequence saved as a string?

Let's have the string `"3:7"`. I would like to get either `c(3,4,5,6,7)`, or `3:7`, anyway with R reading this data as numeric, not as string.

If I do `as.numeric("3:7")` I get a `NA`. Is there any simple way or function in R doing this?

A more complex example:

```
rec_pairs <- list(c("3:7", "1"), c("2,1", "3"), c("NA", "5"), c("6", "NA"))
```

I am interested in obtaining all the distinct elements in the first components of the vectors of the list, that is, `3,4,5,6,7,2,1,NA,6`.

Comment: Just want to point out that the edited example is pretty different from the original. Also, how are you defining distinct if you have 6 twice?

Comment: Regarding to the "distinct" observation, you are right, it is a bad example (both 6 shoud be counted only once)

Comment: But this is not a problem using later `unique`

Comment: Right, but if the example you give doesn't match what you describe, then it's unclear that taking unique values would actually do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use either `eval(parse`

```
eval(parse(text = "3:7"))
```

or `split` and convert use the `seq`

```
Reduce(`:`, scan(text="3:7", sep=":", what = numeric()))
```

---

Based on the new data

```
unlist(sapply(rec_pairs, function(x) lapply(strsplit(x[1], "[,:]"), 
       function(y) Reduce(`:`, as.list(as.numeric(y))))))
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  2  1 NA  6
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I have `"3:7"` in a character vector of expressions result of applying `sapply`. Should I, following the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24975243/997979, add another `sapply` to eval the full vector of expressions or there is a shorter way? Thank you!

Comment: @iago  You can use `strsplit` into a `list` and then do the `Reduce` for each element.  Please check the timings with benchmark

Comment: Following your indication, I try `Reduce(`:`, strsplit(sapply(rec_pairs, function(i) i[1]), split = ",", fixed = TRUE))` with the newer example I added to my question, but I get an error.

Comment: @iago `strsplit` returns a string.  Also, it can be directly applied on `rec_pairs` i.e. `lapply(strsplit(rec_pairs, ",", fixed = TRUE), function(x) Reduce(`:`, as.list(as.numeric(x))))`

Comment: It gives me an error: `rec_pairs` is a list and `strsplit` only applies to vectors. Further I do not want all the elements in `rec_pairs`

Comment: I added to my question

Answer (score 0):

The method of `eval` and `parse` by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395057/12158757) would be the most efficient way. Here is another solution with `base R`:

```
v <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit("3:7",":")))
s <- seq(v[1],v[2])
```

such that

```
> s
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```