# Clean column data in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am stuck with a small problem while trying to clean my data. I have a property data set which has listing of property size as character. Most of the data for the size column is just numeric but in text format. If I convert them to numeric data, I will loose many data due to coercion. There are particular data where it is like (20*40)....which I am unable to convert. As this data is getting coerced to NA while conversion. Any guidance on how to handle this kind of issue?

Comment: Please consider to show a small erperoducible example and expectedd output

Comment: If the value is `20*40` do you need 800 as output?

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975229/in-r-evaluate-expressions-within-vector-of-strings) is what you want please say so and I will delete my answer below and close as duplicate.

Comment: I like all the Answers below, but is there any way to way to wrap the `eval` in something so that it can't get to frisky?  Avoiding the 'Little Bobby Tables' (https://xkcd.com/327/) problem?

Comment: @akrun - Yes....I want output value as 800....

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this function can be of help.

```
evalCell <- function(x){
  f <- function(x) eval(parse(text = x))
  sapply(x, f)
}

x <- c("(20*40)", 123, "1 + 2*3", "(1 + 2)*3")
evalCell(x)
#  (20*40)       123   1 + 2*3 (1 + 2)*3 
#      800       123         7         9
```

If the return vector's names are not wanted, have the function return `unname(sapply(etc))`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `map` with `parse_expr`

```
library(purrr)
map_dbl(x, ~ eval(rlang::parse_expr(.x)))
#[1] 800 123   7   9
```

#### data

```
x <- c("(20*40)", 123, "1 + 2*3", "(1 + 2)*3")
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution....I tried it but it did not work. I am facing the below error...

 Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:4: unexpected symbol
1:  25x75
          ^

Comment: I think i got the issue....its not able to read 'x' as mathematical operation...thats the error is coming....

Comment: @NiMbuS it must be a package version issue as i can't reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sapply(yourColumn, function(X) eval(parse(text=X)))
```

Example:

```
> sapply(c("5+5", "22", "10*5"), function(X) eval(parse(text=X)) )
 5+5   22 10*5 
  10   22   50
```