# Suggestions for avoiding for-loops in R

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to avoid using `for()` loops for my problem. Let's say I have two vectors, for simplicities sake: `x1 <- c(1,10,30)` and `x2 <- c(11,31,40)`. These vectors contain reference points that point to certain intervals in my `df` with variables that each have, in this case, 40 observations. So:
`df(x1[1]:x2[1])` would be the first ten observations. `df(x1[2]:x2[2])` would be next 20 observations with the last (30,40) representing the last 10. I want to calculate multiple statistics including `mean`,`std` and `variance`, for example, for each of the intervals. `for()`-loops will do the trick but its very slow. I was looking at `apply` functions, but i can't seem to figure it out. `mean(df[x1:x2])` also doesn't do the trick as it just takes the first value for `x1` and `x2`.

Any suggestions?

--tstev

Comment: Cna you put your input data.frame ?

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel, its just a simple arbitrary example to keep problem simple. But lets say the data frame looks like this if I were only interested in one variable: `df <- as.data.frame(sample(40))`

Comment: With the variance :)

Comment: Be aware that replacing for-loops with `apply`-type functions does not automatically speed things up (for instance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533246/why-is-apply-method-slower-than-a-for-loop-in-r). Vectorized solutions, on the other hand, probably will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good opportunity to use `Map` with the usefull `each` from `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)

Map(function(u,v) each(mean, sd, var)(df[u:v,1]), x1, x2)

#[[1]]
#    mean        sd       var
#17.90000  10.15929 103.21111  

#[[2]]
#    mean        sd       var
#19.14286  12.18313 148.42857

#[[3]]
#    mean        sd       var 
#24.81818  10.78720 116.36364
```

**Data:**

```
x1 <- c(1,10,30)
x2 <- c(10,30,40)
set.seed(3)
df <- as.data.frame(sample(40))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion! I wish I could select two answers. I am going to go with @Benoit solution because its easier for me to understand. I am not sure whats happening with the `Map` function. The documentation is lacking I find. But that probably due to the fact that I just started with R. :) Thanks a lot in any case!

Comment: Map takes the two vectors x1 and x2. Then apply the function on x1[1] and x2[1]. Then moves up and applies the function on x1[2] and x2[2], and so on.

Comment: Ah I see now. Tested it with my actual dataset and its great actually! With `Map()` I wouldn't need separate statements for each statistic I would like.

Comment: Exactly using Map and each is great functional programming, very compact!

Comment: Very true! It's also faster than `apply` when testing with `microbenchmark` package. Considering I will be recieving a significantly larger dataset as soon as my scripts are fool-proof, `Map()` will prove to be very useful :D

Answer (score 2):

I tend to be averse to using `apply` on rows of a data.frame (as any mis-step upconverts everything to a character class). I've had to do something very similar to what you are asking in other code, and I opted for `mapply`.

It does "something" with the first element of 2 (or more) vectors/lists, then does the same "something" with the second element of the same vectors/lists, etc. The "something" of course is defined by the first argument -- a function, similar to the other `*apply` functions.

```
set.seed(42)
x1 <- c(1,10,30)
x2 <- c(11,31,40)
df <- as.data.frame(sample(40))
ret <- mapply(function(a,b) df[a:b,], x1, x2)
ret
## [[1]]
##  [1] 37 40 11 31 24 19 26  5 22 32 14
## [[2]]
##  [1] 32 14 21 27  7 13 36 25  3 38 12 35 23 18 17  2  8  6 29 30 10 15
## [[3]]
##  [1] 10 15 39  4 33  1 28 34  9 16 20
```

From here it would be trivial to apply any other statistical summaries you want:

```
sapply(ret, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))
##          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
## mean 23.72727 19.13636 19.00000
## sd   10.95528 11.14107 12.87633
```

(Or you could always extend the `mapply` call to directly call these other functions.)

**EDIT #1**:

As suggested by @docendo discimus, `Map` (and `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`) are slightly faster. For comparison:

```
set.seed(3)
x1 <- c(1,11,31)
x2 <- c(10,30,40)
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = sample(40))
df2 <- df1[,,drop = FALSE]
df3 <- df1[,,drop = FALSE]
grp <- rep(seq_along(x1), (x2-x1) + 1L)
df2 <- cbind(df2, grp)

library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(dt=setDT(df1)[, list(mean(V1), sd(V1), var(V1)), by = grp],
               dplyr=df2 %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, var)),
               mapplyT=mapply(function(a,b) { x <- df3[a:b,]; c(mean(x), sd(x), var(x)); }, x1, x2, SIMPLIFY=TRUE),
               mapplyF=mapply(function(a,b) { x <- df3[a:b,]; c(mean(x), sd(x), var(x)); }, x1, x2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE),
               Map=Map(function(a,b) { x <- df3[a:b,]; c(mean(x), sd(x), var(x)); }, x1, x2))
## Unit: microseconds
##     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
##       dt  925.964 1006.9570 1176.5629 1081.4810 1184.7870 2582.434   100
##    dplyr 1843.449 1967.0590 2154.9829 2042.2515 2185.2745 3839.960   100
##  mapplyT  208.398  237.8500  272.8850  260.8315  286.2685  511.846   100
##  mapplyF  187.424  208.6205  237.6805  225.1320  247.2215  445.801   100
##      Map  191.441  215.7610  240.9025  231.6025  258.6005  441.785   100
```

I made explicit deep copies of the data.frame because `setDT` modified the data.frame in place (ergo its efficiency) but `mapply` and `Map` were not able to cope with the data.table. (I baked the `mean`,`sd`,`var` into my `mapply` calls in order to compare apples with apples.)

**EDIT #2**:

The previous benchmarks look impressive and conclusive, but don't depict overhead of calls versus efficiency of large-data engines. Here's another run at things with more data.

When the individual subsets are fairly large -- i.e, fewer "chunks" from the source data.frame -- performance tends to balance out. Here I control chunk size with `k`:

```
n <- 4000
k <- 100
x1 <- c(1, sort(sample(n, size = n/k - 1)))
x2 <- c(x1[-1] - 1, n)
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = sample(n))
df2 <- df1[,,drop = FALSE]
df3 <- df1[,,drop = FALSE]
grp <- rep(seq_along(x1), (x2-x1) + 1L)
df2 <- cbind(df2, grp)

microbenchmark(dt=setDT(df1)[, list(mean(V1), sd(V1), var(V1)), by = grp],
               dplyr=df2 %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, var)),
               mapplyT=mapply(function(a,b) { x <- df3[a:b,]; c(mean(x), sd(x), var(x)); }, x1, x2, SIMPLIFY=TRUE),
               mapplyF=mapply(function(a,b) { x <- df3[a:b,]; c(mean(x), sd(x), var(x)); }, x1, x2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE),
               Map=Map(function(a,b) { x <- df3[a:b,]; c(mean(x), sd(x), var(x)); }, x1, x2))
## Unit: milliseconds
##     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##       dt 2.133063 2.297282 2.549046 2.435618 2.655842 4.305396   100
##    dplyr 2.145558 2.401482 2.643981 2.552090 2.720102 4.374118   100
##  mapplyT 2.599392 2.775883 3.135473 2.926045 3.156978 5.430832   100
##  mapplyF 2.498540 2.738398 3.079050 2.882535 3.094057 7.041340   100
##      Map 2.624382 2.725680 3.158272 2.894808 3.184869 6.533956   100
```

However, if the chunk size is reduced, the already-well-performing `dplyr` comes out ahead by a good margin:

```
n <- 4000
k <- 10
x1 <- c(1, sort(sample(n, size = n/k - 1)))
x2 <- c(x1[-1] - 1, n)
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = sample(n))
df2 <- df1[,,drop = FALSE]
df3 <- df1[,,drop = FALSE]
grp <- rep(seq_along(x1), (x2-x1) + 1L)
df2 <- cbind(df2, grp)

microbenchmark(dt=setDT(df1)[, list(mean(V1), sd(V1), var(V1)), by = grp],
               dplyr=df2 %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, var)),
               mapplyT=mapply(function(a,b) { x <- df3[a:b,]; c(mean(x), sd(x), var(x)); }, x1, x2, SIMPLIFY=TRUE),
               mapplyF=mapply(function(a,b) { x <- df3[a:b,]; c(mean(x), sd(x), var(x)); }, x1, x2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE),
               Map=Map(function(a,b) { x <- df3[a:b,]; c(mean(x), sd(x), var(x)); }, x1, x2))
## Unit: milliseconds
##     expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##       dt 11.494443 12.45187 14.163123 13.716532 14.655883 62.424668   100
##    dplyr  2.729696  3.05501  3.286876  3.148276  3.324098  4.832414   100
##  mapplyT 25.195579 27.67426 28.488846 28.319758 29.247729 32.897811   100
##  mapplyF 25.455742 27.42816 28.713237 28.038622 28.958785 76.587224   100
##      Map 25.184870 27.32730 28.737281 28.198155 28.768237 77.830470   100
```

If you notice, `dplyr` took roughly the same time for the smaller dataset as the larger. Nice.

*There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and statistics.* (Benjamin Disraeli) This applies equally well to benchmarks.

Comment: I think it could be slightly faster using `Map` instead of `mapply`, or specifying `simplify = FALSE` inside `mapply` (since you want a list in return anyway).

Comment: By my benchmarks, `SIMPLIFY=TRUE` reduces the time by around 18% on large data.frames, you're absolutely right. See my edit.

Comment: Nice edit! After seeing the benchmarks I deleted my answer :)

Comment: Be careful with benchmarks; this just indicates how things perform with very small datasets. Things look a bit different when the source data.frame and vectors are larger. Another edit forthcoming.

Comment: True, that was my second thought as well. On the other hand, the original example had overlapping intervals which is different from what I did in my answer.

Comment: Great explanations! Thanks a lot! I am going to take some time to understand this and apply it to my data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
x1 <- c(1,10,30)
x2 <- c(10,30,40)

df <- as.data.frame(sample(40))
df2 <- data.frame(x1,x2)

apply(df2,1, function(x) mean(df[x[1]:x[2],]))
```

Just replace `mean()` by `sd()` or `var()` to get standard deviation or variance. Don't forget the `na.rm=TRUE` argument if you have missing data in `df`.

Comment: Thanks alot! I assume this would also be possible with matrices. From what I understand R works 'faster' with matrices or lists and not so much data.frames.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of a for loop you could use apply twice? The desired computation can be wrapped into a function (in my example it is `compute_mean`), and then one can call this function on pairs of indexes from `x1` and `x2`. Given that `x1` and `x2` are of the same length, it is easy to do with lapply

```
x1 <- c(1,10,30)
x2 <- c(10,30,40)
df <- as.data.frame(sample(40))

compute_mean <- function(df, ind1, ind2, i){
    result <- apply( df[c(ind1[i]:ind2[i]), , drop = F], 2, mean )
    return(result)
}

unlist(lapply(c(1:length(x1)), function(x){
    out <- compute_mean(df = df, ind1 = x1, ind2 = x2, i = x)
    return(out)
}))
```