# How to efficiently sum over levels defined in another variable? 

Tags: r, apply

I am new to R. Now I have a function as follow:

```
funItemAverRating = function()
{
    itemRatingNum = array(0, itemNum);
    print("begin");
    apply(input, 1, function(x)
        {
            itemId = x[2]+1;
            itemAverRating[itemId] <<- itemAverRating[itemId] + x[3];
            itemRatingNum[itemId] <<- itemRatingNum[itemId] + 1;
        }
    );
}
```

In this function input is a `n*3` data frame, `n` is `~6*(10e+7)`, `itemRatingNum` is a vector of size `~3*(10e+5)`.
My question is why the `apply` function is so slow (it would take nearly an hour to finish)? Also, as the function runs, it uses more and more memory. But as you can see, the variables are all defined outside the `apply` function. Can anybody help me?

cheng

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what data looks like (what is `itemAverRating`, what are columns of `input`) but I suppose you could to it without `apply` using vectorization. E.g.: `itemRatingNum[input[[2]]+1] <- itemRatingNum[input[[2]]+1] + 1`

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Is there any efficiency difference between this and the apply function?

Comment: Yes. Operating on vectors if much, much faster (could take you from 1h to <1m)

Comment: @user572138, please change the title of your question. Apply is not slow in general, only in your particular reason, mainly because you are not using it right.

Comment: @mpiktas Ok. Can you provide an scenario where apply process large scale data (such as in my case) efficiently? Thanks.

Comment: @user572138, `apply(x,1,mean)` probably will work fine. Note that I said in general, and your example is specific, i.e. with large scale data. If the data does not fit in memory base R should be used with care. Also I am a bit confused, if you knew that `apply` is slow, why did you use it?

Comment: @mpiktas : I'd use `rowMeans()` for that, which is again a whole lot faster. Apply is about as fast as a for-loop, see also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar

Comment: @Joris, yes I know, I try to keep myself up to date with speed improvements in R,  but the OP asked the example with `apply`.

Comment: @user572138 : edited the title to point out the real question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's slow because you call high-level R functions many times.

You have to *vectorize* your function, meaning that most operations (like `<-` or `+1`) should be computed over all data vectors.

For example it looks to me that `itemRatingNum` holds frequencies of `input[[2]]` (second column of `input` `data.frame`) which could be replaced by:

```
tb <- table(input[[2]]+1)
itemRatingNum[as.integer(names(tb))] <- tb
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I want to do things like: itemPopu = tapply(input[,3], input[,2], sum); Is there any efficient solutions. I find that tapply is very slow.

Comment: Try `rowsum(input[[3]],input[[2]])`

Answer (score 7):

Don't do that. You're following a logic that is completely not R-like. If I understand it right, you want to add to a certain `itemAverRating` vector a value from a third column in some input dataframe.

What `itemRatingNum` is doing, is rather obscure. It does not end up in the global environment, and it just becomes a vector filled with frequencies at the end of the loop. As you define itemRatingNum within the function, the `<<-` assignment will also assign it within the local environment of the function, and it will get destroyed when the function ends.

Next, you should give your function input, and get some output. Never assign to the global environment if it's not necessary. Your function is equivalent to the - rather a whole lot faster - following function, which takes input and gives output :

```
funItemAverRating = function(x,input){
    sums <- rowsum(input[,3],input[,2])
    sumid <- as.numeric(rownames(sums))+1
    x[sumid]+c(sums)
}
```

*FUNCTION EDITED PER MAREKS COMMENT*

Which works like :

```
# make data
itemNum <- 10
set.seed(12)
input <- data.frame(
    a1 = rep(1:10,itemNum),
    a2 = sample(9:0,itemNum*10,TRUE),
    a3 = rep(10:1,itemNum)
)
itemAverRating <- array(0, itemNum)
itemAverRating <- funItemAverRating(itemAverRating,input)
itemAverRating
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
39 65 57 36 62 33 98 62 60 38
```

If I try your code, I get :

```
> funItemAverRating()
[1] "begin"
...
> itemAverRating
 [1] 39 65 57 36 62 33 98 62 60 38
```

Which is the same. If you want itemRatingNum, then just do :

```
> itemRatingNum <- table(input[,2])
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 6 11 11  8 10  6 18  9 13  8
```

Comment: I tried tapply, but I found that the this function is very slow, itemPopu = tapply(input[,3], input[,2], sum); this code would cost a lot of time. Is there any better solutions?

Comment: @user572138 : It's about 13 times faster than your code on my computer and it does exactly the same thing. What do you mean by "slow"?

Comment: In my data, length(input) is very large(~6*10e+7), but there are many repeated items in input[,2]. The unique number of input[,2] is ~3*10e5. When i run tapply(input[,3], input[,2], sum) i need to wait a long time(at least 5 mins). In C, this of course will not cost so long.

Comment: By "at least 5 mins" I mean that after 5 mins, the code still runs.

Comment: The row number of input is about (~6*10e+7).

Comment: @user572138 : What do you expect? You have a huge dataset, and you expect it to be processed as if you have only 1000 datapoints? Quite impossible. I tried it with 1e7 length input and 1e5 different items, and it runs in 11 seconds (compared to 315 seconds for your code). But at one point, you'll pay for the huge dataset you have.

Comment: @Joris You forgot about `rowsum` ;)

Comment: @user572138 : edited the function using rowsum (thx @Marek), now it runs on an input with 1e7 rows and 1e5 different items in only 2.3 seconds (instead of 11) on my computer.

Comment: @user572138 : corrected a mistake in the code. Function as it is now works perfectly for every case.

Comment: Thanks all of you for the great help.