# How to use tapply and preserve order of values

Tags: r

hopefully this is not a too dumb question, but still being an R beginner I have a serious problem with tapply. Lets say

```
factors <- as.factor( c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c") )
values  <- c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 7, NA, NA )
tapply(
  values,
  factors,
  function(x){
    if( sum(is.na(x)) == 1 ){
      x[ is.na(x) ] <- 0
    }
    return(x)
  }
)
```

The result is

```
$a
[1] 1 4 7

$b
[1] 2 5 0

$c
[1]  3 NA NA
```

However, what I need is to get a vector back which preserves the original order of values, i.e.:

```
c( 1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,0,NA )
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This was my first question on stackoverflow and I am very impressed about the fast help I got. So many thanks to all.

Comment: It's because your question is clear, contain all relevant information and data to work with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that case you should use the `ave` function:

```
> ave(values, factors, FUN=function(x) {
+     if( sum(is.na(x)) == 1 ){
+       x[ is.na(x) ] <- 0
+     }
+     return(x)
+   }
+ )
[1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA  7  0 NA
```

Comment: Yeah. The ave function is pretty cool. You just need to remember to explicitly use...  FUN=

Comment: True, took me a couple of minutes to figure out. But still you really made me happy with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop does this very simply:

```
fun <- function(x){
   if(sum(is.na(x)) == 1){x[is.na(x)] <- 0}
       return(x)
}

for (i in unique(factors)){
   values[i == factors] <- fun(values[i == factors])
}
```

Comment: I also thought about that. But aren't all these apply-functions times faster than iterating over the data manually with loops? Especially since computational demand is an issue for my data.

Comment: Not always, tapply and apply are just syntactic sugar. Look at the source for tapply() type `tapply` in the console. I guess the point is really that the number of iterations is going to be small (usually) compared to the length of the data in each.

Comment: I agree with mdsumner, although in this case I believe that DWin's answer using `ave()` is considerably faster than an explicit for loop.

Comment: It might be interesting to test. Sometimes you get surprised.

Comment: @DWin - I did; `ave()` is almost 5 times faster than my `for` loop, (on a 300000 length vector, still with only 3 levels).

Comment: @mdsumner : that's a bit too sharp there. They're more than syntactic sugar, and can give quite a speedup in some cases. See the answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar

Comment: The sugar is sweet, but tapply and apply are not faster - they are R for loops under the hood - by "not always" I meant "at least lapply can be faster" but I didn't want to commit, hence the reference to just these two functions.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use the replacement method for split():

```
## create a copy to store the result after replacement
res <- values

## use split's replacement method to split, apply, and recombine
split(res, factors) <- lapply(split(res, factors),
 function(x){
 if( sum(is.na(x)) == 1 ){
   x[ is.na(x) ] <- 0
 }
  return(x)
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case others found this question by searching for how to disable alphabetic sorting for the groups, you can do this:

```
> v=1:4
> group=c("b","b","a","a")
> tapply(v,group,sum)
a b
7 3
> tapply(v,factor(group,unique(group)),sum)
b a
3 7
```