# Subtract value from each list's element in R

Tags: r

I need to subtract specified value from each list element in R. In [this](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/) article is mentioned that for such tasks the `apply` family of functions are used instead of loops. I've tried following:

```
# Define list
> a = 1:20

# Substraact this from each element
> substract_me = 5

# Function for substracting
> substract = function(x,y) { ret = x-y; return(ret) }

# The problem is that I do not know how to access the current array element and pass it to substract function
lapply(a, substract)
```

[Here](https://rollingyours.wordpress.com/category/r-programming-apply-lapply-tapply/) is mentioned that the anonymous functions can be also used, but it did not worked for me and I get syntax error. Indeed it looks to me just like syntactic sugar. The problem remain the same, that I need some placeholder or something when I am using `lapply` function so I can access the current list element:

```
lapply(a, function([WHAT TO ADD HERE???],substract_me) substract([WHAT TO ADD HERE???],substract_me))
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253159/using-lapply-with-changing-arguments) is something probably related but I did not figure out how stuff works from posted code snippets.

Comment: `a` is not a `list`. Try either `typeof(a)` or `class(a)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Subtraction in R is vectorized

```
a = 1:20
substract_me = 5
a - substract_me
# [1] -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

No need for `apply` functions here.

Comment: May I ask when should I use *apply family of functions?

Comment: @WakanTanka I believe that the apply functions are useful for true list-type objects in r. dataframes and data.tables are two examples of list based objects.

Answer (score 4):

The title of the original question asks for how to apply subtract to a list type r object, but the example given subtracts from a vector `a = 1:20`.

The approved answer by MrFlick is exactly correct for vectors, but does not work with a list. For example, subtracting from the following list of integer vectors fails.

```
a <- list(v1 = 1:10, v2 = -5:5, v3 = 1:5)
# $v1
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# $v2
# [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
# $v3
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
subtract_me <- 5
a - subtract_me # produces a non-numeric argument to binary operator error
```

lapply with an inline-defined anonymous function is an easy way to accomplish the desired subtraction on a list.

```
subtract_me <- 5
lapply(a, function(x, subt_amnt) x - subt_amnt, subt_amnt = subtract_me)
# $v1
# [1] -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
# $v2
# [1] -10  -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   0
# $v3
# [1] -4 -3 -2 -1  0
```

the subtraction function can be defined outside of lapply. Error handling and other checks in the function would likely warrant a standalone function.

For more info on the uses of anonymous functions see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions

As Requested by MoonS, an alternative approach would be to write the function explicitly outside the lapply call.

```
subtract_first_element_only <- function(x, subt_amnt) {
  # insert any additional logic to determine the subtract amount or 
  # from which elements to subtract here
  vector_out <- c(x[1] - subt_amnt,x[2:length(x)])
  return(vector_out)
}

lapply(a, subtract_first_element_only, subt_amnt = subtract_me)

#
```

Comment: I am interested to know if we have subtract_me as a vector of three elements and we want to subtract each element of the list from the corresponding element of the vector using lapply. i.e. subtract_me <- c(5, 3, 4). we want to subtract 5 from v1, 3 from v2 and 4 from v3.how could that be achieved

Comment: @Jisika I'd recommend checking out the mapply function. That lets you pass individual values from the list or vector into a function.

Comment: @icj Thanks for sharing. Is there a way to only subtract from the first element, e.g. -4? Or subtract based on a certain attribute in a dataframe?

Comment: @MoonS That is possible. You'll need to write a more robust function to use inside of lapply. The example I used here is for an anonymous, in line function, but any function sourced in your script could be used. I'll update my answer to show how that would work.