# R: using lapply with data frames and custom function

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a question about using `lapply` with lists of dataframes. Suppose I have two lists:

```
 list1<-list(data1,data2)
 list2<-list(data3,data4)
```

I want to write a function that appends a column and row from one dataframe to another. This is my function:

```
append<-function(origin.data, destin.data){

vec.to.append<-origin.data[,1]

#add as the first column
destin.data<-cbind(vec.to.append, destin.data)

#add as first row
vec.to.append<-t(c(0, vec.to.append))
destin.data<-rbind(vec.to.append, destin.data)

return(destin.data)
}
```

This works fine if I run

```
append(list1[[1]], list2[[1]])
```

or

```
append(list1[[2]], list2[[2]])
```

but gives me an error when I try to use `lapply`:

```
trial<-lapply(list1, append, destin.data=list2)
```

The error looks straightforward:

```
Error in rbind(vec.to.append, destin.data) : number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

but as I checked the dimensions of my dataframes and vector, all looked fine. Plus, the function runs and gives the expected result if I do not use `lapply` but do it "argument by argument". Can somebody help me out?

By the way, I saw the answer here: [Using lapply with changing arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253159/using-lapply-with-changing-arguments) but applying my function over the list names gives an empty result:

```
prova<-lapply(names(list1), append, destin.data=list2)

prova
list()
```

Clearly, I am missing something!

Comment: @nongkrong Thanks. I think I am using `lapply` over a `list` of dataframes, with the intention of applying the function `append` to each `dataframe` element. Indeed, `append` takes two dataframes as inputs and gives a dataframe as output. In short, I am not sure I understand your comment and why it explains my `lapply` failure. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Try `lapply(list1,function(x)apply(x[[1]],x[[2]]))`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks, Michael. Just a clarification: did you mean `lapply(list1, function(x) append(x[[1]], x[[2]]))`? Also, what is `x`? Can you please explain? Thank you.

Comment: your data1-data4 are matrices not data.frames, correct?

Comment: They are `data.frames`.

Comment: `x` is the argument you pass to the anonymous/inline function defined as `apply(x[[1]], x[[2]] )`; it appears I misunderstood your intent, so it won't work quite as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply(list1, append, destin.data=list2)` is equivalent to:

```
list(append(list1[[1]], list2),
     append(list1[[2]], list2)
```

Which is not what you want. If you want to pair up list1 and list2, element-wise, you should do:

`lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i) append(list1[[i]], list2[[i]])`

This is equivalent to:

```
list(append(list1[[1]], list2[[1]]),
     append(list1[[2]], list2[[2]])
```

which is what you do want, right?

edit: as the other answer says, you can also use `mapply`, which is a little tidier, but this is the `lapply`-based solution. Result is the same in either case.

Comment: Yes! That is what I want. I'll give it a try now and report back!

Answer (score 1):

`lapply` only iterates over *one* list. The last argument you pass is passed on to the function as-is (i.e. the function `append` gets passed all of `list2` rather than just one element).

You can use [`Map`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) or [`mapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html) instead. Note that the order of the arguments here is reversed in comparison to `lapply`:

```
result = Map(append, list1, list2)
```